# Table and multi-page

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking

I'm writing some sort of book and i've got a very large table.

I was wondering if there was a way to span a table not in the length but in the width.

In the end, i would like to be able to divide the table in two parts such that once the book is printed, it would be possible to follow a line through 2 pages.

Is there a way or a package to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's an automatic way to do this, but, if your table has fixed height rows, you can split it into two tables and use the `dpfloat` package to pair the two tables on adjacent pages.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dpfloat, booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}

\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\midrule
0.598064154 & 0.339685582 & 0.19396861 & 0.213309634 & 0.075210499 & 0.332646254 \\
0.078241148 & 0.792167857 & 0.219108081 & 0.201291187 & 0.431479589 & 0.667717852 \\
0.469795242 & 0.33942751 & 0.420695486 & 0.82740107 & 0.738145761 & 0.031280146 \\
0.753119695 & 0.951982884 & 0.785708805 & 0.818329289 & 0.359288584 & 0.290605686 \\
0.803870396 & 0.731847731 & 0.899035306 & 0.8203372 & 0.762518297 & 0.025427827 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{leftfullpage}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}

\toprule
7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\midrule
0.060659362 & 0.594518703 & 0.735081007 & 1.735081007 & 2.735081007 & 3.735081007 \\
0.494861845 & 0.452771499 & 0.6161709 & 1.6161709 & 2.6161709 & 3.6161709 \\
0.685467538 & 0.929017242 & 0.866804413 & 1.866804413 & 2.866804413 & 3.866804413 \\
0.557379459 & 0.670159594 & 0.252399841 & 1.252399841 & 2.252399841 & 3.252399841 \\
0.303340706 & 0.958921469 & 0.339461931 & 1.339461931 & 2.339461931 & 3.339461931 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{fullpage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The big downside with this solution is that if you have columns in which the lines wrap in one table, you will need to manually add struts in the corresponding rows of the other table to make them line up.

It also restricts you to having the split table on pages by themselves; you can't split a table across just the top part of two pages, for example.

Comment: you missed the ... `begin{document}`. Excellent solution!

Comment: @Alan Munn: `dpfloat` is nearly what I'm searching for, however if on the left page there is a **caption**, the tables are not perfectly aligned vertically! :-(

Answer (score 11):

only possible with `ConTeXt`, with `LaTeX` it is some kind of handy craft ...
The code for context mkiv of Alans example:

```
\starttext
\setuplinetable[width=.19\textwidth]

\startlinetable
\NC 1           \NC2           \NC3           \NC4           \NC5           \NC6 
\NC7            \NC 8          \NC9           \NC10          \NC11          \NC12 \NR
\NC 0.598064154 \NC0.339685582 \NC0.19396861  \NC0.213309634 \NC0.075210499 \NC0.332646254 
\NC 0.078241148 \NC0.792167857 \NC0.219108081 \NC0.201291187 \NC0.431479589 \NC0.667717852 \NR
\NC 0.469795242 \NC0.33942751  \NC0.420695486 \NC0.82740107  \NC0.738145761 \NC0.031280146 
\NC 0.753119695 \NC0.951982884 \NC0.785708805 \NC0.818329289 \NC0.359288584 \NC0.290605686 \NR
\NC 0.803870396 \NC0.731847731 \NC0.899035306 \NC0.8203372   \NC0.762518297 \NC0.025427827 
\NC 0.060659362 \NC0.594518703 \NC0.735081007 \NC1.735081007 \NC2.735081007 \NC3.735081007 \NR
\NC 0.494861845 \NC0.452771499 \NC0.6161709   \NC1.6161709   \NC2.6161709   \NC3.6161709 
\NC 0.685467538 \NC0.929017242 \NC0.866804413 \NC1.866804413 \NC2.866804413 \NC3.866804413 \NR
\NC 0.557379459 \NC0.670159594 \NC0.252399841 \NC1.252399841 \NC2.252399841 \NC3.252399841 
\NC 0.303340706 \NC0.958921469 \NC0.339461931 \NC1.339461931 \NC2.339461931 \NC3.339461931 \NR
\stoplinetable

\stoptext
```

And here the output of the two pages 1 and 2 
[image]

Comment: and how would one do such a thing in ConTeXt?

Comment: `\startlinetable ... \stoplinetable`

Comment: @Juan: see example

Answer (score -2):

Everyone's answers seem way too convoluted... how about the [`longtable` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=longtable)? It breaks over pages automatically, you just set it up like a normal table and it takes care of everything for you.

Comment: it breaks the tabular vertically but not in horizontal direction.

Comment: @Herbert - gah, I've been lied to. Well, in that case, you could rotate the table contents by 90°, then rotate the table itself 90° back... if you were masochistic, anyway.

Comment: I was tempted to do it this way, but was hoping for a ... cleaner solution.