# Is there a "widetable" counterpart to "longtable"?

Tags: tables, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table and multi-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/table-and-multi-page)

I have some tables with 25 columns that don't fit on the page, even after rotating with `sidewaystable`. I know about `longtable` but what I would need is `widetable`. Does it exist?

I have also seen solutions with `\mbox`, but that's a bit hackish for me. I generate these tables with some general R code I have (general in that in most cases it's not taking 25 columns), so I can always go back and make it more robust if some `widetable` package doesn't exist. Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8959/2693 The short answer is that there isn't a simple way to do this, but there are ways.

Comment: @Alan: Good! In such cases you could vote to close the question with the reason that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @richardh: Does the question that Alan linked to answer your question?  If so, we'll close this one as a duplicate (just to keep the place tidy!).  If not, please edit your question to clarify why that one doesn't help so that people can better focus their energies on helping you.

Comment: @Stefan: Alan can't vote to close yet since he's a bit below 3000 rep.

Comment: @all -- Yeah, this is a duplicate and I'd vote to close if I could. Those are good answers that I couldn't find with google. It is odd that Alan's answer didn't pop up in my searches here since it's voted up and recent. Is there a way to add "wide" or "too many columns" to that question? Or I guess that's what my closed question will do :). Thanks!

Comment: @richardh: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, your question should stay even if closed, so that future searches will point to the right answer.

Comment: Closing as a dupe based on the above