# Split one label into many and append with a, b, c, etc

Tags: numbering, cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I am making one table into two (or more) and would like them to have the same label *number* for these two tables, but append them with an "a" or "b" to differentiate them. Also, I would like to be able to refer to them in the text by just the number, not as number.a and number.b. And I would like to retain LaTeX's assume table numbering.

For example, a table that LaTeX would later number as 8 is too big to fit on one page, so I split it up manually and want it to be automatically labeled 8a and 8b and referred to as 8 in the text. Does this exist? I am sure that I'm searching the wrong keywords, again.

The back story is that I create tables with scripts in R. [I looked for a widetable package here yesterday and there are some good solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/is-there-a-widetable-counterpart-to-longtable), but not for the scripts I already have (although I'd like to later add them). Plus it sounds like a good skill to have. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ccaption` package allows for "continuation captions". So to implement what you want, you could do the following (adapted from the `ccaption` documentation.)

## Update

Since you wanted the first table to have a letter suffix as well, I've changed the code to allow two commands: `\splittablecaption` and `\splittablecaption*`. This also removes the need to manually reset the subtable caption counter.  Use the starred version for the first in the series, and the unstarred version for any subsequent ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\newcounter{splittab}
\renewcommand{\thesplittab}{\alph{splittab}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\splittablecaption}{\@ifstar\splittablecaptionstar\splittablecaptionplain}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\splittablecaptionplain}[1]{\stepcounter{splittab}\captiondelim{\thesplittab: }\contcaption{#1}}
\newcommand{\splittablecaptionstar}[1]{\setcounter{splittab}{0}\stepcounter{splittab}\captiondelim{\thesplittab: }\caption{#1}}

% Usage: for a split table, use \splittablecaption*{} for the initial caption
% and \splittablecaption{} for the subsequent captions
% There is no need to reset the counters manually, as this is done inside the 
% starred version of the \splittablecaption command.


\begin{document}


\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption*{A multi-part table} \label{tab:m}
 \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 1 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption{Continued} \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 2 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption{Concluded} \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 3 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}

\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption*{A multi-part table} \label{tab:m}
 \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 1 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption{Continued} \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 2 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}
\begin{table} \centering \splittablecaption{Concluded} \begin{tabular}{lc} \hline
just a single line & 3 \\ \end{tabular} \end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Alan FTW, again. Is there a way I can make the tables 1a, 1b, 1c instead of 1, 1a, 1b? In my tinkering I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard I've changed the code to reflect this; it's actually nicer now.

Comment: I don't understand what's happened to your code blocks.  I just went to edit your answer to put them in but the preview showed the code properly as code.  That's bizarre.

Comment: @Alan -- Perfect! Thanks so much! I always forget that latex is also a programming language.

Comment: I took a bow at a venture and added a couple of new lines at the end of the code (your `\end{document}` had no newline after it) and that appears to have fixed it.  I'll see if this has been reported on meta.SO.

Comment: @Andrew I think we may have been editing at the same time.  I made a change to the code and then forgot to re-format it.  That might have been what you saw.  But I immediately re-edited and fixed the code.

Comment: Ah, okay!  Good thing I didn't go and make a fool of myself on meta.SO.  Ooops, too late.  I hope that your answer doesn't get made CW on the back of this ...

Comment: @Andrew no it won't become CW unless I edit it more than 10 times, or more than 5 different users edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subcaption` package in the following way, this package comes now shipped with the `caption` package, and has similar options.

```
\begin{table}
     \subcaptionbox{\label{t1a} Caption for table a}%
      {\begin{tabular}<spec>
       <things here>
       \end{tabular}}
     \subcaptionbox{\label{t1b} Caption for table b}%
      {\begin{tabular}<spec>
       <things here>
       \end{tabular}}
     \subcaptionbox{\label{t1c} Caption for table c}%
      {\begin{tabular}<spec>
       <things here>
       \end{tabular}}
     \caption{\label{t} Caption for all tables
\end{table}
```

In this way, you can reference each table separately, or just the bunch of them with the label t.

Comment: I don't think this will work for Richard's purposes: his problem is that the subtables span multiple pages.  The `subfigure` package is designed for multiple small figures or tables within a single float.

Comment: @Alan You are right. I forgot about the multiple pages part.