# Multipage tables (column-wise)

Tags: tables, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table and multi-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/table-and-multi-page)

I have a table with a lot of sideways content. Like the following table:

```
           A  B  ...  X    Y   Z
Entry 1    
Entry 2
Entry 3
```

The table however is too long to fit on one page. How can I format the table as following

```
            A  B  C  D  E  F
Entry 1    
Entry 2
Entry 3
---- Page Break ----
           ...       X  Y  Z
Entry 1    
Entry 2
Entry 3
```

I know that there is a package `longtable` that does the same thing but over the rows. (Repeating the headers). However in this case it is preferable that the output is in the way as described. 
There is also a package `sidewaystables`, but there are too many columns to fit the page even sideways.

Comment: To be able to comment on your question after migration (and accept an answer), please register your account here and there (with the same mail address).

Comment: Can be done _only_ with ConTeXt. Search for it, I gave some time ago an example

Comment: Duplicate of [Table and multipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8959/2693)