# Is there something like "sidewayslongtable"?

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating

Unfortunately my table is too wide to use `longtable`.

In `sideways` it fits on width.

Unfortunately it's too long to fit on one page.

Is there something like `sidewayslongtable`, a way to combine `sideways` with `longtable` ?

P.S. I use `pdflatex`. 'pdflscapes' (and 'lcapes') are almost perfect except one thing: they do not only rotate content of page (like `sideways`) but also page itself. I would like to rich result, as proposed 'pdflscapes'+'longtable' but without pages being rotated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Table and Multipage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8959/2693).

Comment: Is it, really? What he wants is a sideway (rotated) table continuing from one page to another, not a large table split on two pages (and possibly continuing on two other pages).

Comment: o far, I've split it manually. But I am looking forward more automatic solutions for future tables. I used to generate reports automatically, so automatic solution for splitting tables would be great addition.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheDubacq I think you're right.

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on David's answer, you can use the `lscape` (or `pdflscape`) package to put a `longtable` into a series of landscape pages.

If you use the `lscape` package, the content of pages is rotated; if you use the `pdflscape` package, the physical pages in the PDF are also rotated.

Here's a schematic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % or {lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}
...
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Crucially you can't use the `table` environment here, but the `longtable` package provides a `\caption` command to add captions to the table and the TOC for these sorts of tables.

Comment: Longtable has it's own caption command that should work here

Comment: It's almost was I am looking for, without one detail : not only contents is rotated, those pages are rotated! I am looking for solution, which will rotate contents (like `sideways` not pages it-self). Even thou, it's very interesting to now about such option :).

Comment: The `lscape` pacckage rotates just the content, I think.  The `pdflscape` package just adds the extra functionality of rotating the physical pages.

Comment: The rotation of the pages is only a matter of your PDF reader, as far as the headers and footes are where you want to have them (which is, I suppose, on the sorter sides).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.  I forgot about that.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: In my case `lscape` simply fails. Two pages go away, and only third is seen. @AlanMunn What about "just reader rotates it", with `sidewaystable` it doesn't - and this is the way I would like it to work - that's why title is "sidewayslongtable".

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki If you're having problems with `lscape` update your question with a minimal example that shows the issue.

Comment: I could not rotate the longtable, I tried using \landscape environment but it just rotates the page, not the table content

Answer (score 8):

I think you are looking for the [`lscape`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape) package.

Comment: This is a funny forum here: quite often, somebody with deep knowledge of TeX & Friends puts the whole thing on the right track. And others refine the answer to make it easier to use those wonderfull packages. Maybe this is an upside of (La-, Con-, Lua-)TeX which is not reckognized often enough: we depend on cooperation.

Comment: Actually I have problems with 'lscapes' (it "eats" pages, leaving only last in document), but it is not a problem, cause `pdflscapes` work. There is different problem : both packages rotates not only content, but pages as well. Is there a way to achieve the same effect as `pdflscape`, but without rotating pages (just content, like `sideways` does) ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by rotating pages not content. lscape just rotates the page body leaving the page header and footer in their original portrait orientation. (For reading on screen the pdf viewer may rotate the page so the main content is more readable but tjis shouldn;t affect printing.

Comment: `lscape` is a supported part of the latex distribution, so if you can make a miminmal example where it goes wrong please run `latex latexbug` and follow the instructions to send in a bug report (category `graphics`) and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you use pdflatex (not latex), it is possible to change the papersize midway of a document (I hacked geometry.sty, which you are surely using already, just to do that). My solution is not compatible with many output hacks (afterpage, for example; I am not sure how floats would work, too). If this fits your use case (i.e. you are not stuck with dvi or postscript because of PStricks, for example), just leave a comment for more details (basically, you need to redefine margins and paper size). This way, you have pages in landscape mode in the middle of your document. This is one solution, I am sure there are others.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you mean changing size for whole document ? I would need to put this table inside of a book, so I can not change geometry for whole document.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind, you might think about is : generating pages with table separately on "landscape" pages, next - includepdf . It's interesting workaround :). However, lest look for most integrated solution.