# Long and wide table

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there something like “sidewayslongtable”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44221/is-there-something-like-sidewayslongtable)

I've got some long and wide table which I want to add to my phd thesis. Is there a package that could help me with that. I know `longtable` helps for long tables, handling the header etc. I would need a package that places the table on double pages and that cares about the table alignment and proper heading etc. Any ideas?

Comment: I added a possible duplicate, however, now I recognize that your question seem to be a bit different. I think that you should explain better what you want: You really want to have half of the columns on the left-hand page and second half of the columns on the right-hand page? The question I linked to provides a variant that you put the table sideways (rotated).

Comment: Thanks for the link. There I found what I was after: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/table-and-multi-page

Comment: Unfortunatelly it seems there is no automatic way to do yet.

Comment: @MichaelBölling, I had a similar problem. Only that my tables were too wide, meaning they didn't even fit when using landscape. I didn't want transposing the tables, so I needed to break them column-wise with repeating the column header on the next page. David Carlisle provided me with me some semi-automated approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables