# Column-wise break of extra wide tables

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I have to plot geochemical data tables that are like this table

[image: from Martin, P.M. and Mason, B. (1974). Major and trace elements in the Allende meteorite. Nature 249(5455): 333-334]

, i.e. with a **header column**, but that have much more sample columns. When having too many columns, the table has to be broken at a certain column, and to be continued on the next page; most importantly, the header column has to be repeated (like in the `\longtable` environment, only transposed).

This has been *sort-of* discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681498/very-wide-tables-in-latex

However, there is only manual solutions for this problem. Has there been any more progress to automate a "column-wise table break"?

(I don't think that transposing my over-wide tables, to make it a long table, is very helpful in terms of legibility.)

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}

    Sample &   Sample 1 &   Sample 2 &   Sample 3 &   Sample 4 &   Sample 5 &   Sample 6 &   Sample 7 &   Sample 8 &   Sample 9 &  Sample 10 &  Sample 11 &  Sample 12 &  Sample 13 &  Sample 14 &  Sample 15 &  Sample 16 &  Sample 17 &  Sample 18 &  Sample 19 &  Sample 20 &  Sample 21 &  Sample 22 &  Sample 23 &  Sample 24 \\

Major element abundances (wt\%) &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

      SiO2 &         25 &         81 &         36 &         75 &         23 &         21 &         65 &         84 &          1 &         59 &         38 &         16 &          3 &         56 &         29 &         34 &          3 &         59 &         55 &         17 &          2 &         81 &         59 &         43 \\

      TiO2 &         48 &         96 &          0 &         90 &         61 &         72 &         83 &         16 &         10 &          1 &         40 &         83 &         35 &         31 &         76 &         31 &         57 &          8 &         83 &        100 &         14 &         12 &         48 &         69 \\

     Al2O3 &          7 &         14 &         99 &         53 &         89 &         65 &         88 &         17 &         76 &         81 &         43 &         87 &         15 &         71 &         17 &         85 &         59 &        100 &         96 &         85 &         74 &         50 &         59 &         36 \\

     Fe2O3 &         32 &         34 &         23 &         86 &         50 &         58 &          8 &         29 &         88 &         27 &         49 &         16 &         19 &         89 &         45 &         88 &         79 &         42 &         42 &         29 &         10 &         60 &         87 &         97 \\

      FeOt &         35 &         42 &         83 &          0 &         55 &         51 &         35 &         11 &         43 &         44 &         69 &         30 &         49 &         55 &         56 &          4 &         74 &         72 &         98 &         94 &         14 &         35 &         59 &         34 \\

       MnO &         64 &         48 &         52 &         65 &         61 &         16 &         73 &         56 &         73 &         54 &         75 &          7 &         18 &         84 &         52 &         38 &         46 &         91 &         59 &         90 &         31 &         84 &         54 &         32 \\

       MgO &         48 &         97 &         83 &         47 &         43 &         41 &         37 &         71 &         92 &         57 &         76 &         36 &          8 &         37 &         94 &          6 &         50 &         57 &         80 &         63 &         25 &         18 &         85 &         16 \\

       CaO &         56 &         11 &         68 &         49 &          6 &         20 &         31 &         74 &         72 &         24 &         39 &         38 &         68 &         69 &         73 &         23 &         40 &         32 &         63 &         93 &         28 &         56 &         12 &         18 \\

      Na2O &         73 &         18 &          0 &         62 &         98 &         61 &         59 &         42 &         97 &         47 &         74 &         31 &         40 &          3 &         75 &          2 &         52 &         96 &         67 &         44 &         84 &          9 &         35 &         51 \\

       K2O &         69 &          0 &         52 &         73 &         23 &         11 &         12 &         70 &         86 &         46 &         29 &         84 &         77 &         47 &         25 &         43 &         97 &         48 &         30 &         94 &         83 &         93 &         23 &         25 \\

      P2O5 &         92 &         80 &         59 &          6 &         90 &         99 &         54 &         64 &         96 &         84 &         58 &         18 &         37 &          7 &         55 &         89 &         34 &         53 &         59 &         56 &         38 &         23 &         63 &         89 \\

      LOI§ &         51 &         65 &         64 &          2 &         67 &         51 &         58 &         55 &         60 &         48 &         64 &         54 &         56 &         46 &         78 &         70 &         38 &         44 &         45 &         37 &         66 &          7 &         34 &         76 \\

       Mg# &         20 &         27 &         34 &         40 &         66 &          3 &          7 &         42 &         19 &         85 &         35 &         24 &         31 &         40 &         14 &         39 &         31 &        100 &          0 &         41 &         19 &         14 &         75 &          5 \\

       CIA &         24 &         57 &          1 &         80 &         86 &         72 &         38 &         11 &         51 &         23 &         49 &         94 &         43 &         65 &         15 &          5 &         41 &         21 &         32 &         83 &         22 &         16 &         63 &         51 \\

Trace element abundances (ppm) &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\

         V &         91 &        421 &        256 &        480 &        669 &        888 &        403 &        456 &        661 &         77 &        997 &        729 &        647 &         77 &         69 &        163 &         52 &        589 &        772 &        267 &        110 &        998 &        547 &        789 \\

        Cr &        635 &        712 &        208 &        938 &        754 &        600 &         91 &        531 &        211 &        798 &        880 &        240 &        197 &        671 &        298 &        921 &        538 &        577 &         49 &        195 &        596 &        744 &        719 &        910 \\

        Co &        288 &        182 &        672 &        825 &        197 &        466 &        204 &        803 &        943 &        321 &        444 &        134 &        471 &         22 &        191 &        188 &        457 &        481 &        288 &        971 &        475 &        906 &        261 &        243 \\

        Ni &        492 &        234 &         46 &         62 &        213 &        531 &        808 &        557 &        599 &        356 &        681 &        487 &        929 &         36 &        729 &         84 &        962 &        918 &        260 &        688 &        373 &        363 &        679 &         51 \\

        Cu &        675 &        494 &        754 &        743 &        119 &        404 &        142 &        402 &        120 &        643 &        576 &        135 &        870 &        205 &        639 &        775 &        549 &         82 &        933 &        222 &         55 &        567 &        672 &        354 \\

        Zn &        440 &        656 &        667 &        193 &        305 &        758 &        814 &        660 &        811 &        519 &        885 &        488 &        223 &        182 &        120 &        448 &         58 &        830 &        173 &        473 &        847 &        809 &         22 &        456 \\

        Ga &        782 &        639 &        282 &        906 &        595 &         39 &        901 &         73 &        825 &        330 &        937 &        860 &         48 &        920 &        968 &        150 &        967 &        838 &        819 &        997 &        430 &        635 &        959 &        672 \\

        Rb &        422 &        930 &        404 &        581 &        916 &        747 &        970 &         87 &        343 &        784 &        843 &        339 &        919 &        398 &        827 &        265 &        216 &        382 &        772 &         17 &        770 &        745 &        543 &        224 \\

        Sr &        468 &         17 &        860 &        996 &        938 &        416 &        594 &        506 &        226 &        572 &        507 &        432 &         54 &        484 &        517 &        629 &        793 &        721 &        743 &        481 &        306 &        948 &        387 &        239 \\

        Pb &        429 &        280 &         83 &        495 &        980 &        715 &        225 &        540 &         58 &        513 &        653 &        149 &        893 &        918 &        553 &        879 &        136 &        266 &        900 &        811 &        942 &        706 &        344 &        528 \\

         U &        669 &        507 &        455 &        714 &         83 &         39 &         83 &        175 &        466 &        940 &        794 &        232 &        600 &        327 &        590 &        723 &        597 &        759 &        377 &        214 &        372 &        627 &        746 &        102 \\

        Cs &        408 &        615 &        657 &        539 &        612 &        907 &        615 &        820 &        650 &        133 &        870 &        605 &        691 &        190 &        741 &        245 &        370 &        486 &        269 &        475 &        258 &        320 &        909 &        204 \\

         Y &        291 &        830 &        767 &        872 &        522 &        639 &        159 &        548 &        236 &        718 &        701 &        762 &        965 &        323 &        770 &        688 &         22 &         11 &        930 &        329 &        657 &        778 &        432 &        581 \\

        Zr &        902 &        131 &        233 &        211 &        399 &        315 &        730 &        852 &         76 &        973 &        350 &        887 &        201 &        895 &        691 &        885 &        223 &        830 &        690 &        477 &        424 &        756 &        659 &        166 \\

        Nb &        594 &        969 &        833 &        663 &        243 &        154 &        197 &        104 &        317 &        834 &        901 &        891 &        997 &        934 &        328 &        261 &        982 &        581 &        781 &        933 &        625 &        783 &        711 &        354 \\

        Ba &        790 &        957 &        606 &        730 &        754 &        928 &        646 &          0 &        389 &         71 &        616 &        434 &        107 &        126 &        692 &        118 &        983 &         24 &        281 &        808 &        743 &        381 &        139 &        856 \\

        La &        624 &        859 &        233 &        176 &        540 &        138 &        188 &        475 &        478 &        203 &        614 &         53 &        435 &        694 &         66 &        860 &        628 &        271 &        338 &        799 &        924 &        877 &        777 &        721 \\

        Ce &        826 &        471 &        327 &        809 &        496 &        180 &        378 &        155 &         61 &        345 &        736 &        341 &        201 &        634 &        393 &        932 &        498 &        334 &         29 &        319 &        254 &         79 &        691 &         52 \\

        Pr &        476 &        447 &        951 &        786 &        450 &        717 &        248 &        790 &        561 &        259 &        748 &        104 &        881 &        804 &        385 &        676 &        435 &        815 &        634 &        234 &        809 &        105 &        471 &        529 \\

        Nd &        758 &        523 &        672 &        159 &        405 &        597 &        657 &        307 &         28 &         28 &         30 &        273 &         74 &        189 &        403 &        326 &         19 &        735 &        121 &        992 &         26 &        723 &        243 &        927 \\

        Sm &        307 &        422 &        764 &        933 &        197 &        180 &        956 &        276 &        347 &        492 &        534 &        760 &        904 &        247 &          0 &        518 &        593 &        714 &        223 &        619 &        634 &         39 &        265 &        445 \\

        Eu &        463 &        194 &        627 &        954 &         32 &        940 &        824 &        229 &         58 &        684 &        780 &        761 &        348 &        464 &         39 &        577 &        432 &        920 &        425 &        799 &          3 &        207 &        208 &        398 \\

        Gd &        863 &        274 &        512 &        718 &        770 &        900 &        221 &        674 &        342 &        553 &        522 &        945 &        880 &         23 &        605 &        544 &        214 &        987 &        348 &        445 &        763 &        893 &        607 &        162 \\

        Tb &        162 &        547 &         73 &        216 &        420 &        242 &        451 &        196 &        987 &        649 &        184 &        256 &        218 &         86 &        962 &        203 &         37 &        494 &        286 &        663 &        612 &        549 &        537 &        594 \\

        Dy &        265 &         21 &        889 &        312 &        756 &         94 &        976 &        188 &        147 &        839 &        527 &        442 &        849 &        948 &        570 &        553 &        902 &        290 &         81 &        758 &        759 &        598 &        344 &        104 \\

        Ho &        218 &        503 &        999 &        465 &        573 &        586 &        122 &        991 &        241 &        710 &        182 &         87 &        965 &        746 &         90 &        638 &         35 &        122 &        389 &        892 &        815 &        617 &        116 &        895 \\

        Er &        571 &        932 &        738 &        653 &        986 &        430 &        992 &        432 &        823 &        542 &        444 &        702 &        524 &         58 &        248 &        914 &        697 &        420 &        913 &        754 &        596 &        429 &        995 &        927 \\

        Tm &        551 &         72 &        654 &        819 &        593 &          7 &        110 &        707 &        535 &         74 &        142 &        150 &        610 &        564 &        859 &        451 &        832 &        822 &        938 &        877 &        954 &        430 &         41 &        657 \\

        Yb &        815 &        643 &        650 &        217 &        962 &        612 &        926 &        524 &        559 &        500 &        822 &        630 &        901 &        525 &        407 &        563 &        575 &        161 &        505 &        166 &        207 &        680 &        418 &        478 \\

        Lu &        106 &        597 &        551 &        650 &        391 &        850 &        589 &        649 &          6 &        277 &        129 &        566 &        109 &        922 &        767 &        173 &        525 &        250 &        449 &        662 &        221 &        831 &        969 &        479 \\

        Hf &        100 &        833 &        566 &        331 &         36 &        589 &         33 &        785 &        862 &        447 &        469 &        284 &        329 &        116 &        608 &        256 &        665 &         41 &         74 &        527 &        479 &        300 &        800 &         51 \\

        Ta &        337 &        757 &        903 &        411 &        745 &        638 &        243 &        584 &        336 &        477 &        994 &        307 &        349 &        981 &        572 &        364 &        822 &        609 &        198 &        478 &        922 &        854 &        819 &        130 \\

        Th &       1000 &        520 &        222 &        998 &        774 &         88 &        843 &        259 &        424 &        845 &        884 &        739 &        666 &        673 &        531 &        934 &        322 &        682 &        754 &        944 &        153 &        779 &         20 &        890 \\

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be nice if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with some sample data to play around with, in best case as compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The original version (below the line) tried to make less syntax changes in the table,
this one introduces a few more changes but makes it easy to change the page breaks without doing any coding, and doesn't require the same number of columns on each page.

There are usage comments in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{tablepage}
\makeatletter

% #1 no of pages
% #2 caption
% #3 table 
% table usesnormal tabular except
% Replace & by \thbreak after column(s) you want repeated.
% replace & by \tbreak at points you want page to break.
% must be a \tbreak before final \\
% any nested tabulars must be inside {} to hide the &
% \multicolumn is allowed but can not span a break.
% might want to replace \cleardoublepage by a cmmand to get onto left pf speread
% the tabular preamble needs as many columns (including heading columns) as the 
% page with the most columns.
\long\def\widesplit#1#2#3{%
\def\row{\rowz\c@tablepage}%
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{tablepage}{0}%
\loop
\refstepcounter{tablepage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}\centering
 \ifnum\c@tablepage=\@ne
    \captionof{table}{#2}%
 \else
\captionof*{table}{#2 (page \thetablepage\ of #1)}%
 \fi
#3\end{minipage}%
\clearpage
\ifnum#1>\c@tablepage
\repeat}

\begin{document}

\def\rowa#1\thbreak#2\tbreak#3\\{#1&#2\\}

\def\rowz#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\@ne
    \expandafter\rowa
  \else
    \expandafter\rowq\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
  \fi}

\def\rowq#1#2\thbreak#3\tbreak{\rowz{#1}#2\thbreak}
\centering
\footnotesize

\widesplit{5}{some boring numbers}{%
\begin{tabular}{>\bfseries{l}rrrrr}
\row
    Sample \thbreak   Sample 1 &   Sample 2 &   Sample 3 &   Sample 4 &   Sample 5 \tbreak   Sample 6 &   Sample 7 &   Sample 8 &   Sample 9 &  Sample 10 \tbreak  Sample 11 &  Sample 12 &  Sample 13 &  Sample 14 &  Sample 15 \tbreak  Sample 16 &  Sample 17 &  Sample 18 &  Sample 19 &  Sample 20 \tbreak  Sample 21 &  Sample 22 &  Sample 23 &  Sample 24 \tbreak\\[2ex]
\row
\rlap{Major element abundances (wt\%)} \thbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            \tbreak\\
\row
      SiO2 \thbreak         25 &         81 &         36 &         75 &         23 \tbreak         21 &         65 &         84 &          1 &         59 \tbreak         38 &         16 &          3 &         56 &         29 \tbreak         34 &          3 &         59 &         55 &         17 \tbreak          2 &         81 &         59 &         43 \tbreak\\
\row
      TiO2 \thbreak         48 &         96 &          0 &         90 &         61 \tbreak         72 &         83 &         16 &         10 &          1 \tbreak         40 &         83 &         35 &         31 &         76 \tbreak         31 &         57 &          8 &         83 &        100 \tbreak         14 &         12 &         48 &         69 \tbreak\\
\row
     Al2O3 \thbreak          7 &         14 &         99 &         53 &         89 \tbreak         65 &         88 &         17 &         76 &         81 \tbreak         43 &         87 &         15 &         71 &         17 \tbreak         85 &         59 &        100 &         96 &         85 \tbreak         74 &         50 &         59 &         36 \tbreak\\
\row
     Fe2O3 \thbreak         32 &         34 &         23 &         86 &         50 \tbreak         58 &          8 &         29 &         88 &         27 \tbreak         49 &         16 &         19 &         89 &         45 \tbreak         88 &         79 &         42 &         42 &         29 \tbreak         10 &         60 &         87 &         97 \tbreak\\
\row
      FeOt \thbreak         35 &         42 &         83 &          0 &         55 \tbreak         51 &         35 &         11 &         43 &         44 \tbreak         69 &         30 &         49 &         55 &         56 \tbreak          4 &         74 &         72 &         98 &         94 \tbreak         14 &         35 &         59 &         34 \tbreak\\
\row
       MnO \thbreak         64 &         48 &         52 &         65 &         61 \tbreak         16 &         73 &         56 &         73 &         54 \tbreak         75 &          7 &         18 &         84 &         52 \tbreak         38 &         46 &         91 &         59 &         90 \tbreak         31 &         84 &         54 &         32 \tbreak\\
\row
       MgO \thbreak         48 &         97 &         83 &         47 &         43 \tbreak         41 &         37 &         71 &         92 &         57 \tbreak         76 &         36 &          8 &         37 &         94 \tbreak          6 &         50 &         57 &         80 &         63 \tbreak         25 &         18 &         85 &         16 \tbreak\\
\row
       CaO \thbreak         56 &         11 &         68 &         49 &          6 \tbreak         20 &         31 &         74 &         72 &         24 \tbreak         39 &         38 &         68 &         69 &         73 \tbreak         23 &         40 &         32 &         63 &         93 \tbreak         28 &         56 &         12 &         18 \tbreak\\
\row
      Na2O \thbreak         73 &         18 &          0 &         62 &         98 \tbreak         61 &         59 &         42 &         97 &         47 \tbreak         74 &         31 &         40 &          3 &         75 \tbreak          2 &         52 &         96 &         67 &         44 \tbreak         84 &          9 &         35 &         51 \tbreak\\
\row
       K2O \thbreak         69 &          0 &         52 &         73 &         23 \tbreak         11 &         12 &         70 &         86 &         46 \tbreak         29 &         84 &         77 &         47 &         25 \tbreak         43 &         97 &         48 &         30 &         94 \tbreak         83 &         93 &         23 &         25 \tbreak\\
\row
      P2O5 \thbreak         92 &         80 &         59 &          6 &         90 \tbreak         99 &         54 &         64 &         96 &         84 \tbreak         58 &         18 &         37 &          7 &         55 \tbreak         89 &         34 &         53 &         59 &         56 \tbreak         38 &         23 &         63 &         89 \tbreak\\
\row
      LOI§ \thbreak         51 &         65 &         64 &          2 &         67 \tbreak         51 &         58 &         55 &         60 &         48 \tbreak         64 &         54 &         56 &         46 &         78 \tbreak         70 &         38 &         44 &         45 &         37 \tbreak         66 &          7 &         34 &         76 \tbreak\\
\row
       Mg\# \thbreak         20 &         27 &         34 &         40 &         66 \tbreak          3 &          7 &         42 &         19 &         85 \tbreak         35 &         24 &         31 &         40 &         14 \tbreak         39 &         31 &        100 &          0 &         41 \tbreak         19 &         14 &         75 &          5 \tbreak\\
\row
       CIA \thbreak         24 &         57 &          1 &         80 &         86 \tbreak         72 &         38 &         11 &         51 &         23 \tbreak         49 &         94 &         43 &         65 &         15 \tbreak          5 &         41 &         21 &         32 &         83 \tbreak         22 &         16 &         63 &         51 \tbreak\\[2ex]
\row
\rlap{Trace element abundances (ppm)} \thbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            &            \tbreak            &            &            &            \tbreak\\
\row
         V \thbreak         91 &        421 &        256 &        480 &        669 \tbreak        888 &        403 &        456 &        661 &         77 \tbreak        997 &        729 &        647 &         77 &         69 \tbreak        163 &         52 &        589 &        772 &        267 \tbreak        110 &        998 &        547 &        789 \tbreak\\
\row
        Cr \thbreak        635 &        712 &        208 &        938 &        754 \tbreak        600 &         91 &        531 &        211 &        798 \tbreak        880 &        240 &        197 &        671 &        298 \tbreak        921 &        538 &        577 &         49 &        195 \tbreak        596 &        744 &        719 &        910 \tbreak\\
\row
        Co \thbreak        288 &        182 &        672 &        825 &        197 \tbreak        466 &        204 &        803 &        943 &        321 \tbreak        444 &        134 &        471 &         22 &        191 \tbreak        188 &        457 &        481 &        288 &        971 \tbreak        475 &        906 &        261 &        243 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ni \thbreak        492 &        234 &         46 &         62 &        213 \tbreak        531 &        808 &        557 &        599 &        356 \tbreak        681 &        487 &        929 &         36 &        729 \tbreak         84 &        962 &        918 &        260 &        688 \tbreak        373 &        363 &        679 &         51 \tbreak\\
\row
        Cu \thbreak        675 &        494 &        754 &        743 &        119 \tbreak        404 &        142 &        402 &        120 &        643 \tbreak        576 &        135 &        870 &        205 &        639 \tbreak        775 &        549 &         82 &        933 &        222 \tbreak         55 &        567 &        672 &        354 \tbreak\\
\row
        Zn \thbreak        440 &        656 &        667 &        193 &        305 \tbreak        758 &        814 &        660 &        811 &        519 \tbreak        885 &        488 &        223 &        182 &        120 \tbreak        448 &         58 &        830 &        173 &        473 \tbreak        847 &        809 &         22 &        456 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ga \thbreak        782 &        639 &        282 &        906 &        595 \tbreak         39 &        901 &         73 &        825 &        330 \tbreak        937 &        860 &         48 &        920 &        968 \tbreak        150 &        967 &        838 &        819 &        997 \tbreak        430 &        635 &        959 &        672 \tbreak\\
\row
        Rb \thbreak        422 &        930 &        404 &        581 &        916 \tbreak        747 &        970 &         87 &        343 &        784 \tbreak        843 &        339 &        919 &        398 &        827 \tbreak        265 &        216 &        382 &        772 &         17 \tbreak        770 &        745 &        543 &        224 \tbreak\\
\row
        Sr \thbreak        468 &         17 &        860 &        996 &        938 \tbreak        416 &        594 &        506 &        226 &        572 \tbreak        507 &        432 &         54 &        484 &        517 \tbreak        629 &        793 &        721 &        743 &        481 \tbreak        306 &        948 &        387 &        239 \tbreak\\
\row
        Pb \thbreak        429 &        280 &         83 &        495 &        980 \tbreak        715 &        225 &        540 &         58 &        513 \tbreak        653 &        149 &        893 &        918 &        553 \tbreak        879 &        136 &        266 &        900 &        811 \tbreak        942 &        706 &        344 &        528 \tbreak\\
\row
         U \thbreak        669 &        507 &        455 &        714 &         83 \tbreak         39 &         83 &        175 &        466 &        940 \tbreak        794 &        232 &        600 &        327 &        590 \tbreak        723 &        597 &        759 &        377 &        214 \tbreak        372 &        627 &        746 &        102 \tbreak\\
\row
        Cs \thbreak        408 &        615 &        657 &        539 &        612 \tbreak        907 &        615 &        820 &        650 &        133 \tbreak        870 &        605 &        691 &        190 &        741 \tbreak        245 &        370 &        486 &        269 &        475 \tbreak        258 &        320 &        909 &        204 \tbreak\\
\row
         Y \thbreak        291 &        830 &        767 &        872 &        522 \tbreak        639 &        159 &        548 &        236 &        718 \tbreak        701 &        762 &        965 &        323 &        770 \tbreak        688 &         22 &         11 &        930 &        329 \tbreak        657 &        778 &        432 &        581 \tbreak\\
\row
        Zr \thbreak        902 &        131 &        233 &        211 &        399 \tbreak        315 &        730 &        852 &         76 &        973 \tbreak        350 &        887 &        201 &        895 &        691 \tbreak        885 &        223 &        830 &        690 &        477 \tbreak        424 &        756 &        659 &        166 \tbreak\\
\row
        Nb \thbreak        594 &        969 &        833 &        663 &        243 \tbreak        154 &        197 &        104 &        317 &        834 \tbreak        901 &        891 &        997 &        934 &        328 \tbreak        261 &        982 &        581 &        781 &        933 \tbreak        625 &        783 &        711 &        354 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ba \thbreak        790 &        957 &        606 &        730 &        754 \tbreak        928 &        646 &          0 &        389 &         71 \tbreak        616 &        434 &        107 &        126 &        692 \tbreak        118 &        983 &         24 &        281 &        808 \tbreak        743 &        381 &        139 &        856 \tbreak\\
\row
        La \thbreak        624 &        859 &        233 &        176 &        540 \tbreak        138 &        188 &        475 &        478 &        203 \tbreak        614 &         53 &        435 &        694 &         66 \tbreak        860 &        628 &        271 &        338 &        799 \tbreak        924 &        877 &        777 &        721 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ce \thbreak        826 &        471 &        327 &        809 &        496 \tbreak        180 &        378 &        155 &         61 &        345 \tbreak        736 &        341 &        201 &        634 &        393 \tbreak        932 &        498 &        334 &         29 &        319 \tbreak        254 &         79 &        691 &         52 \tbreak\\
\row
        Pr \thbreak        476 &        447 &        951 &        786 &        450 \tbreak        717 &        248 &        790 &        561 &        259 \tbreak        748 &        104 &        881 &        804 &        385 \tbreak        676 &        435 &        815 &        634 &        234 \tbreak        809 &        105 &        471 &        529 \tbreak\\
\row
        Nd \thbreak        758 &        523 &        672 &        159 &        405 \tbreak        597 &        657 &        307 &         28 &         28 \tbreak         30 &        273 &         74 &        189 &        403 \tbreak        326 &         19 &        735 &        121 &        992 \tbreak         26 &        723 &        243 &        927 \tbreak\\
\row
        Sm \thbreak        307 &        422 &        764 &        933 &        197 \tbreak        180 &        956 &        276 &        347 &        492 \tbreak        534 &        760 &        904 &        247 &          0 \tbreak        518 &        593 &        714 &        223 &        619 \tbreak        634 &         39 &        265 &        445 \tbreak\\
\row
        Eu \thbreak        463 &        194 &        627 &        954 &         32 \tbreak        940 &        824 &        229 &         58 &        684 \tbreak        780 &        761 &        348 &        464 &         39 \tbreak        577 &        432 &        920 &        425 &        799 \tbreak          3 &        207 &        208 &        398 \tbreak\\
\row
        Gd \thbreak        863 &        274 &        512 &        718 &        770 \tbreak        900 &        221 &        674 &        342 &        553 \tbreak        522 &        945 &        880 &         23 &        605 \tbreak        544 &        214 &        987 &        348 &        445 \tbreak        763 &        893 &        607 &        162 \tbreak\\
\row
        Tb \thbreak        162 &        547 &         73 &        216 &        420 \tbreak        242 &        451 &        196 &        987 &        649 \tbreak        184 &        256 &        218 &         86 &        962 \tbreak        203 &         37 &        494 &        286 &        663 \tbreak        612 &        549 &        537 &        594 \tbreak\\
\row
        Dy \thbreak        265 &         21 &        889 &        312 &        756 \tbreak         94 &        976 &        188 &        147 &        839 \tbreak        527 &        442 &        849 &        948 &        570 \tbreak        553 &        902 &        290 &         81 &        758 \tbreak        759 &        598 &        344 &        104 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ho \thbreak        218 &        503 &        999 &        465 &        573 \tbreak        586 &        122 &        991 &        241 &        710 \tbreak        182 &         87 &        965 &        746 &         90 \tbreak        638 &         35 &        122 &        389 &        892 \tbreak        815 &        617 &        116 &        895 \tbreak\\
\row
        Er \thbreak        571 &        932 &        738 &        653 &        986 \tbreak        430 &        992 &        432 &        823 &        542 \tbreak        444 &        702 &        524 &         58 &        248 \tbreak        914 &        697 &        420 &        913 &        754 \tbreak        596 &        429 &        995 &        927 \tbreak\\
\row
        Tm \thbreak        551 &         72 &        654 &        819 &        593 \tbreak          7 &        110 &        707 &        535 &         74 \tbreak        142 &        150 &        610 &        564 &        859 \tbreak        451 &        832 &        822 &        938 &        877 \tbreak        954 &        430 &         41 &        657 \tbreak\\
\row
        Yb \thbreak        815 &        643 &        650 &        217 &        962 \tbreak        612 &        926 &        524 &        559 &        500 \tbreak        822 &        630 &        901 &        525 &        407 \tbreak        563 &        575 &        161 &        505 &        166 \tbreak        207 &        680 &        418 &        478 \tbreak\\
\row
        Lu \thbreak        106 &        597 &        551 &        650 &        391 \tbreak        850 &        589 &        649 &          6 &        277 \tbreak        129 &        566 &        109 &        922 &        767 \tbreak        173 &        525 &        250 &        449 &        662 \tbreak        221 &        831 &        969 &        479 \tbreak\\
\row
        Hf \thbreak        100 &        833 &        566 &        331 &         36 \tbreak        589 &         33 &        785 &        862 &        447 \tbreak        469 &        284 &        329 &        116 &        608 \tbreak        256 &        665 &         41 &         74 &        527 \tbreak        479 &        300 &        800 &         51 \tbreak\\
\row
        Ta \thbreak        337 &        757 &        903 &        411 &        745 \tbreak        638 &        243 &        584 &        336 &        477 \tbreak        994 &        307 &        349 &        981 &        572 \tbreak        364 &        822 &        609 &        198 &        478 \tbreak        922 &        854 &        819 &        130 \tbreak\\
\row
        Th \thbreak       1000 &        520 &        222 &        998 &        774 \tbreak         88 &        843 &        259 &        424 &        845 \tbreak        884 &        739 &        666 &        673 &        531 \tbreak        934 &        322 &        682 &        754 &        944 \tbreak        153 &        779 &         20 &        890 \tbreak\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

This is with manual choice of break but you only enter it as one table, and only give the heading column once, so easier than explicitly using two tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\def\widesplit#1{%
\cleardoublepage
\def\row##1##2{##1}%
#1%
\clearpage
\def\row##1##2{##2}%
#1%
\clearpage
}
\begin{document}

\widesplit{%
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c|*{13}{c}}
head 1
\row{&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&i&j&k&l&m}{&n&o&p&q&r&s&t&u&v&w&x&y&z}\\
head 2
\row{&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&i&j&k&l&m}{&n&o&p&q&r&s&t&u&v&w&x&y&z}\\
head 3
\row{&A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I&J&K&L&M}{&N&O&P&Q&R&S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z}
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

---

**Original version:**

---

Variants of this can be customised to the table at hand, so in the table added to the edited question and with captions as requested in comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\long\def\widesplit#1#2{%
\cleardoublepage
\let\row\rowa
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
\captionof{table}{#1}%
#2\end{minipage}%
\clearpage
\let\row\rowb
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
\captionof*{table}{#1 (continued)}%
#2\end{minipage}%
\cleardoublepage
\let\row\rowc
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
\captionof*{table}{#1 (continued)}%
#2\end{minipage}%
\clearpage
\let\row\rowd
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
\captionof*{table}{#1 (continued)}%
#2\end{minipage}%
\clearpage
}
\begin{document}

\def\rowa#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&#8\\{#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7\\}
\def\rowb#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&{\rowa#1&}
\def\rowc#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&{\rowb#1&}
\def\rowd#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&#8{\rowc#1&#8&\\}

\centering
\footnotesize

\widesplit{some boring numbers}{%
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l*{12}r}
\row
    Sample &   Sample 1 &   Sample 2 &   Sample 3 &   Sample 4 &   Sample 5 &   Sample 6 &   Sample 7 &   Sample 8 &   Sample 9 &  Sample 10 &  Sample 11 &  Sample 12 &  Sample 13 &  Sample 14 &  Sample 15 &  Sample 16 &  Sample 17 &  Sample 18 &  Sample 19 &  Sample 20 &  Sample 21 &  Sample 22 &  Sample 23 &  Sample 24 \\[2ex]
\row
Major element abundances (wt\%)\hspace{-3cm} &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            &            \\
\row
      SiO2 &         25 &         81 &         36 &         75 &         23 &         21 &         65 &         84 &          1 &         59 &         38 &         16 &          3 &         56 &         29 &         34 &          3 &         59 &         55 &         17 &          2 &         81 &         59 &         43 \\
\row
      TiO2 &         48 &         96 &          0 &         90 &         61 &         72 &         83 &         16 &         10 &          1 &         40 &         83 &         35 &         31 &         76 &         31 &         57 &          8 &         83 &        100 &         14 &         12 &         48 &         69 \\
\row
     Al2O3 &          7 &         14 &         99 &         53 &         89 &         65 &         88 &         17 &         76 &         81 &         43 &         87 &         15 &         71 &         17 &         85 &         59 &        100 &         96 &         85 &         74 &         50 &         59 &         36 \\
\row
     Fe2O3 &         32 &         34 &         23 &         86 &         50 &         58 &          8 &         29 &         88 &         27 &         49 &         16 &         19 &         89 &         45 &         88 &         79 &         42 &         42 &         29 &         10 &         60 &         87 &         97 \\
\row
      FeOt &         35 &         42 &         83 &          0 &         55 &         51 &         35 &         11 &         43 &         44 &         69 &         30 &         49 &         55 &         56 &          4 &         74 &         72 &         98 &         94 &         14 &         35 &         59 &         34 \\
\row
       MnO &         64 &         48 &         52 &         65 &         61 &         16 &         73 &         56 &         73 &         54 &         75 &          7 &         18 &         84 &         52 &         38 &         46 &         91 &         59 &         90 &         31 &         84 &         54 &         32 \\
\row
       MgO &         48 &         97 &         83 &         47 &         43 &         41 &         37 &         71 &         92 &         57 &         76 &         36 &          8 &         37 &         94 &          6 &         50 &         57 &         80 &         63 &         25 &         18 &         85 &         16 \\
\row
       CaO &         56 &         11 &         68 &         49 &          6 &         20 &         31 &         74 &         72 &         24 &         39 &         38 &         68 &         69 &         73 &         23 &         40 &         32 &         63 &         93 &         28 &         56 &         12 &         18 \\
\row
      Na2O &         73 &         18 &          0 &         62 &         98 &         61 &         59 &         42 &         97 &         47 &         74 &         31 &         40 &          3 &         75 &          2 &         52 &         96 &         67 &         44 &         84 &          9 &         35 &         51 \\
% shortened as tex.sx system complained answer too long
\row
        Th &       1000 &        520 &        222 &        998 &        774 &         88 &        843 &        259 &        424 &        845 &        884 &        739 &        666 &        673 &        531 &        934 &        322 &        682 &        754 &        944 &        153 &        779 &         20 &        890 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this looks good, thank you! i wish there was an automated \widetable command, though, for extremely large tables, see edit

Comment: Hi David, this works fine, but not within the \table environment: splitted tables are placed below each other (on one page). However, I need to place captions, and probably footnotes.

Comment: You really don't want to put a multi-page table in  table environment(s) (the latex float algorithm has no way to keep the parts together) Use the caption (or capt-of package) to allow you to use \captionof{table}{my caption} (and continuation captions on the later pages) wrrap `#1` in a minipage within the definition then each tabular will be in a minipage and footnotes will work

Comment: OK, I'm hopeless, I don't know where to put the \minpage environment. there's a \def command in the preamble and several for each \rowa,b,c,d before \tabular. either way, latex reports "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode."

Comment: captions and minipages added

Comment: Wow, this is super nice! :)

Comment: One more detail: How does one repeat the "Table XX" description on the following pages like in longtable?

Comment: That's what the `\caption*` from the caption package is doing I used it at the top of each page in the definition, it allows a repeat caption without using (and incrementing) the number. The caption package has several other variants of caption formatting you could use instead

Comment: OK, I used \addtocounter{table}{-1} to label the table, but I read, that this will result in some \hyperref problems.

Comment: yes if you make the cross refs active hyperref  won't know which caption to jump to, easiest is probably to use `\captionof*{table}{Table \thetable: #1 (continued)}`

Comment: I don't fully understand how `\def\rowa#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&#8\\{#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7\\}
\def\rowb#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&{\rowa#1&}
\def\rowc#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&{\rowb#1&}
\def\rowd#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&#8{\rowc#1&#8&\\}` works. in the above example one column ("Sample 18") is called twice. As I understand correctly you counted the actual number of columns and then split them up to place them evenly on each page. Is there a way to make  this work for _n_ columns? (I'm not the brightest in coding...)

Comment: yes column 18 is a cheat, the macro that picks out the columns for actual typesetting delimits on `&` but in the last case it has `\\` in the original source, so I inserted an extra `&` in the rowd macro `&\\}`  I could probably make a macro that produced the necessary definitions for given the number of columns to put on each page and the number of columns in the table, will look later.

Comment: thanks David, this makes it easier! however, i'm just wondering: is it much more trickier to break columns instead of lines for apparently a complete automatisation of this process doesn't exist?

Comment: yes:-)  You could use a \valign` based markup but then you would enter the data column wise  but latex doesn't really use valign (although there are some answerers on this site) but if you enter the data row-wise it ends up looking like a paragraph with lots of lines, so it is like setting a paragraph with a too-wide line width and then after the line breaking has happened to split each line in half and put half on each page, it's sort of possible but TeX doesn't help much. and you end up with all kinds of conditions about what works and what does not.

Answer (score 4):

`\widesplit`   also work with longtable...

`longtable` + `widesplit` : is awesome...   extra Long Table on Wide and Height

recently i make a pdf with  6000 page and work perefectly (7 columns x 3000 row)

here my example(short)

```
 \documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{array} 
\textheight = 20cm 
\textwidth = 18cm 
\topmargin = -2cm 
\oddsidemargin= -1cm 
\parindent = 0mm 
% Title Page 
%\title{Prueba Reporte} 
%\author{Hernan Neuman} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addtolength{\headheight}{100pt} % espacio para la raya 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % grosor 0.5pt 
\def\widesplit#1{%   
\def\row##1##2##3{##1} 
 #1 
 \clearpage 
 \def\row##1##2##3{##2} 
 #1 
 \clearpage 
 \def\row##1##2##3{##3} 
 #1 
 \clearpage 
 } 
%%% ---------------- Cabecera ---------  
 \lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} 
    \begin{picture}(0,0) 
    % Figura 
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{imagenes/header.png}} 
    % Texto 
        \put(0,0){ 
        \parbox[t]{90mm}{ 
        \begin{flushright} 
        \begin{scriptsize} 
        \textsf{} 
        \end{scriptsize} 
        \end{flushright} 
        } 
    } 
    \end{picture}} 
%%% ---------------- Pie  de pagina ---------  
 \begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|l|p{3cm}|c|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|l|p{3cm}|l|p{3cm}|l|}\hline  
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{ORDEN DE ADQUISICI'ON} \\  
\hline  
$Industrias Dayan$ &    $0241-555-66-77$ &  $Calle$ &   $Numero Telefonico$ & $Ciudad$  \\  
\hline  
\end{longtable}  
\end{center}     
\begin{center} 
 \widesplit{% 
\begin{longtable}{|*{8}{p{5.600000cm}|}}\hline 
\row{$loc\_case$&$ state$&$ loc\_rack$}{$ taxes\_id$&$ track\_incoming$&$ track\_outgoing$}{$ track\_production$&$ price\_margin$} \endhead \hline 
 \row{loc\_case& state& loc\_rack :D }{ taxes\_id& track\_incoming& track\_outgoing :D }{ track\_production& price\_margin} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & In Development& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & End of Lifecycle& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \row{ False & False& False :D }{ False& False& False :D }{ False& 1.0} \\\hline 
 \end{longtable} 
 } 
\end{center} 
 \end{document}
```

PD:  sorry for my bad english xD

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: How is this different from David's solution?