# Table spanning two pages horizontally?

Tags: tables

Is there a way to have the overflow of a table too wide for the page to continue horizontally on the next page?

I'm trying to create two pages with a table each where every row is adjacent to same row on the other page and this seems like the best way to make sure the row heights are equal, other that strutting and measuring, which seems like a pain.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables/93810#93810

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.