# Cutting a table along columns

Tags: tables, longtable

How do I split a table by its columns?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllllllllllll}
very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text\\
very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text\\
very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text & very long text
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This compiles into a 3 row table, with about 5 columns visible. Now I would like to have the rest (meaning the next 5 columns) displayed after a page break, and if there if anything more to show, again a page break and than the remaining columns, and so on. That in the end, after printing the document, I can glue the sheets together to get a really wide table.

And as a option, if possible, for printout without glueing, it would be helpfull, if it would be able to repeat the first column on each page.

I have in mind something a little bit like longtable, but cutting over the sides instead of the bottom. Does such a solution exists?

I have seen examples of rotating, which does not work because its even wider than landscape. Also I have seen example code which puts columns i to n into one table, adding a newpage and another table featuring columns n+1 to m; this also does not work, because I don't know at the moment where to split the table later.

Comment: This may help. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables