# table on a double page

Tags: tables, longtable, ltablex

I'm having a really wide table with lots of rows. Transposing or splitting is not an option. Searching the internet did not lead to any usefull findings. is the a possibility to build a table like this:

[image]

Here is an example in landscape. But the fontsize ist verysmall(7).

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,numbers=noenddot,twoside,openright,fleqn,appendixprefix,BCOR5mm]{scrbook}

%Text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Dokument in deutsch inklusive Silbentrennung nach neuer deutscher Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Koma für Kopfzeilen
\usepackage{color} % Farbiger Text
\usepackage{setspace} %Einstellen des Zeilenabstandes
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\keepXColumns

\newcommand\rota[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1\ }}
\newcommand*\flatdimension[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{D}{\begin{tabular}{D}#2\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand*\dimension[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{D}{\rota{\begin{tabular}{D}#2\end{tabular}}}}
\newcommand*\charakteristik[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{\rota{\begin{tabular}{D}#1\end{tabular}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{
\begin{spacing}{0.7}
\newlength{\sepf}
\setlength{\sepf}{1pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} %default 6pt

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcolumntype{O}{>{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}l}
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}c}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\fontsize{7}{10}\selectfont}c}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\columncolor{white}}C}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}C}

\begin{longtable}{@{}DDO *{20}{GW}G W@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{19}{c}{} &\multicolumn{25}{D}{Geschäftsmodellentwicklungsprozess}\\
\cmidrule(l{\sepf}){20-44} 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{16}{D}{Softwareeigenschaften} & \multicolumn{21}{D}{Generierung} & \multicolumn{2}{D}{Bewertung} & \multicolumn{2}{D}{Implementierung}\\ 
\cmidrule(r{\sepf}){4-19} \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){20-40} \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){41-42} \cmidrule(l{\sepf}){43-44}   

\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \dimension{4}{Plattform} & \dimension{3}{Kosten} & \dimension{2}{Sprache} & \dimension{3}{Export} & \dimension{2}{Import} & \dimension{2}{Zugriff} & \dimension{3}{\begin{tabular}{ll}Zusätzliche\\ Canvas-Typen\end{tabular}} & \dimension{5}{\begin{tabular}{ll}Benutzer-\\unterstützung\end{tabular}} & \dimension{2}{Darstellung} &\dimension{2}{Dokumentation} & \dimension{6}{\begin{tabular}{ll}Kreativitäts-\\werkzeuge\end{tabular}} & \dimension{3}{Versionierung} & \dimension{2}{Finanzübersicht} & \dimension{2}{Integration}\\

\cmidrule(r{\sepf}){4-7}            \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){8-10}   \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){11-12} 
\cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){13-15}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){16-17}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){18-19}
\cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){20-22}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){23-27}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){28-29} 
\cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){30-31}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){32-37}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){38-40}
\cmidrule(l{\sepf}r{\sepf}){41-42}  \cmidrule(l{\sepf}){42-44}

&&
% Plattform
& \charakteristik{Android} & \charakteristik{iOS}
& \charakteristik{Desktop} & \charakteristik{Webbrowser}
% Kosten
& \charakteristik{keine} & \charakteristik{einmalig} & \charakteristik{regelmäßig}
% Sprache
& \charakteristik{mehrsprachig} & \charakteristik{einsprachig}
% Export
& \charakteristik{Daten} & \charakteristik{Grafik} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Import
& \charakteristik{Daten} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Zugriff
& \charakteristik{parallel} & \charakteristik{seriell}
% Zusätzliche Canvas Typen
& \charakteristik{Custom Canvas} & \charakteristik{vorhanden} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Benutzerunterstützung
& \charakteristik{Clusteranalyse} & \charakteristik{Community} & \charakteristik{Wizard} 
& \charakteristik{Erläuterugen} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Darstellung
& \charakteristik{strukturiert} & \charakteristik{unstrukturiert}
% Dokumentation
& \charakteristik{Annotation}   & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Kreativitätswerkzeuge
& \charakteristik{Brainstorming} & \charakteristik{Hypothesen} & \charakteristik{Interview} & \charakteristik{Journal} & \charakteristik{Umfragen} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Versionierung
& \charakteristik{automatisch} & \charakteristik{manuel} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Finanzübersicht
& \charakteristik{vorhanden} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
% Integration
& \charakteristik{vorhanden} & \charakteristik{nicht vorhanden}
\\ \midrule \endhead
\multirow{9}{*}{\rota{Nicht-Unterstützend}}& \multirow{12}{*}{\rota{Individual}}
  & Business Model Canvas Startup & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Canvas (BMC)                  & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Business Model                &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Business Model Canvas Nechy   &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Business Model Canvas Vree    &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Business Canvas Model         &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & BizCanvas                     &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Canvas Model Design           &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & BMCANVAS                      &   &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\ \cmidrule{1-1}
\multirow{13}{*}{\rota{Test}}
& & Business Model Developer      & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x & x & x &   & x &   & x & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   & x \\
& & Business Model Toolbox        &   & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   & x \\
& & Archi                         &   &   & x &   & x &   &   &   & x & x & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x & x &   \\ \cmidrule{2-2}
& \multirow{10}{*}{\rota{Test}}
  & BiZZdesign                    &   &   & x &   &   & x & x & x &   & x & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   \\
& & bmdesigner                    &   &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Business Model Fiddle         &   &   &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x \\
& & Canvanizer                    &   &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x \\
& & Canvanizer 2.0 (beta)         &   &   &   & x & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x \\
& & LeanLaunchLab                 &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   &   & x & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & LeanMonitor                   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x & x &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Lienzo                        &   &   &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
& & Mural.ly                      &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   &   & x &   &   &   &   & x & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   & x &   & x &   &   &   & x &   & x \\
& & TUZZit                        &   &   &   & x & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   & x & x &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   & x &   & x &   & x \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{40}{C}{[$^1$] von Viacheslav Nechyporenko, [$^2$] von Mathijs Vreeman}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `landscape` page orientation and then use a long table. If you provide some code to start with you will get more accurate answers. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I've added example code of my current version.

Comment: you could look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables/93810#93810

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's worth a look!

Answer (score 5):

You can hide some columns on one page and other on the other page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Table part 1}
\newcolumntype{\somecolumns}{llllllHHHHH}
\begin{tabular}{\somecolumns}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
A& a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j\\
B& a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Table part 2}
\newcolumntype{\somecolumns}{lHHHHHlllll}
\begin{tabular}{\somecolumns}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\\hline
A& a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j\\
B& a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If the tabular is in some external file you don't need to repeat it. But it is difficult to combine this with many rows (over more than one page).

Comment: You should probably make it into `\vphantom`, or use some invisible rule, so that the column height is counted in, no? (If I miss something, I apologize)

Comment: @yo' In the example it is not needed as all columns have the same height . Imho it could get difficult to take the height of the hidden columns into account as it would depend on the column type.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's right; it would need much more careful handling. I just hope the OP won't be surprised at some moment :-)