# How can I separate a multi-page table (e.g. using longtable) by columns?

Tags: tables, longtable, labels, columns

I have a table with a lot of columns (about Model-Statistics). I already tried to use a (rotated) longtable, but I failed because I need to duplicate the first column and not the first row as a "header".

For example I would need to have the Columnes "Variables, Model 1, Model 2" on one page and "Variables, Model 3 & Model 4" on a another page.

If that is not possible, maybe someone knows if it is possible to label two separate tables as one (for the table index) (e.g. label Table 1 & Table 2 both as "Table 1")?

Edit: I am using the APA7-Man-class

Comment: I'd be tempted just to use your editor to make two tables, but you can do this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93810/1090

Comment: for the two table question use caption package `\caption*` for an unnumbered caption that you can call (continued) or whatever you want)