# Landscape multi-page tables using tabularx

Tags: longtable, tabularx, threeparttable, sidewaystable

I am wondering how to split a large table with many columns (54 now but could go up to 90) to:

1. fill multiple pages
2. reprint the first column containing labels on each page
3. reprint `tablenotes` on each page if possible

Thus far I have the MWE below.
In this example I'd like the table to split after column with Distance 1405.
Should I resort to `longtable` somehow? It did not seem useful here as I dont intend to have many rows and would rather not transpose the layout, but granted, I am not sure whether it is something the package is capable of

PS I'm using a custom thesis document class (essentially a modified `report` class) with multiple nested files - `geometry` I believe is as follows if it's needed to address this issue

`\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=25mm, bmargin=25mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}`

[image]

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, tabularx, ragged2e, tabulary, longtable, threeparttable} % tables
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
        \usepackage{graphicx, rotfloat, float}

\begin{sidewaystable}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Whole-rock geochemistry data for the Eriksfjord Group arenites and its fenite}
        \label{AppB-ICP-ALS}
        \tiny
        \sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                     *{54}{S[table-format=2.2]}}
        \toprule    
        {\textit{Sample}} & {KS19-15-QT 3.4} & {KS19-15-QT 3.5} & {KS19-15-QT 3.6} & {KSL 15-1a} & {KS19-15-QT 2.1} & {KS19-15-QT 2.2} & {KS19-15-QT 2.3} & {KS19-15-QT 2.9} & {KS19-15-QT 2.10} & {KSL T3-04a} & {KS19-6-QT 1.1} & {KS19-6-QT 1.2} & {KS19-6-QT 1.3} & {KS19-14-QT 1.1} & {KS19-14-QT 1.2} & {KS19-14-QT 1.3} & {KS19-10-QT 3.1} & {KS19-10-QT 3.2} & {KS19-10-QT 3.3} & {KS19-3-8c} & {KS19-3-8d} & {KS19-10-QT 2.1} & {KS19-10-QT 2.2} & {KS19-10-QT 2.3} & {KS19-18-QT 1.1} & {KS19-18-QT 1.2} & {KS19-18-QT 1.3} & {KSL 14-3a} & {KSL 2-3c} & {LRS19.42} & {KSL 6-1b} & {KSL 1-3a} & {KSL 1-3b} & {KSL 6-3b} & {KSL 6-8b} & {KS19-3-1a} & {KS19-18-2} & {KSL 8-2c} & {KSL 10-4} & {KS19-3-5} & {KS19-3-6} & {KS19-18-12} & {KS19-18-11} & {KS19-3-7} & {KS19-18-9} & {KS19-18-8} & {KSL 15-2} & {KSL 15-4} & {KS19-3-9} & {KSL 15-3a} & {KS19-18-7} & {KS19-3-10} & {KS19-18-5} & {KSL 10-3b} \\ 
        {\textit{Analysed at}} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/AL}S & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {ALS} & {BVC/ALS} \\ 
        {\textit{Category}} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D2EF} & {D2EF} & {D2EF} & {D2EF} & {D2EF} & {D3EF} & {D3EF} & {D3EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EF} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} & {EU} \\ 
        {\textit{Distance (m)}} & 450 & 450 & 450 & 1130 & 1210 & 1210 & 1210 & 1210 & 1210 & 1310 & 1405 & 1405 & 1405 & 2105 & 2105 & 2105 & 2440 & 2440 & 2440 & 1280 & 1280 & 1630 & 1630 & 1630 & 215 & 215 & 215 & 98 & 130 & 148 & 150 & 156 & 156 & 156 & 330 & 420 & 430 & 446 & 2570 & 850 & 1065 & 1190 & 1195 & 1210 & 1340 & 1480 & 1560 & 1560 & 1560 & 1580 & 1605 & 1790 & 1930 & 2340 \\ 
        \midrule
        {\textit{Easting}} & 61.0345 & 61.0346 & 61.0346 & 61.0361 & 61.0309 & 61.0308 & 61.0309 & 61.0312 & 61.0311 & 61.0342 & 61.0300 & 61.0299 & 61.0298 & 61.0258 & 61.0259 & 61.0259 & 61.0247 & 61.0247 & 61.0248 & 61.0337 & 61.0337 & 61.0320 & 61.0321 & 61.0322 & 61.0258 & 61.0259 & 61.0260 & 61.0275 & 61.0403 & 61.0420 & 61.0339 & 61.0433 & 61.0433 & 61.0433 & 61.0411 & 61.0383 & 61.0309 & 61.0303 & 61.0269 & 61.0360 & 61.0354 & 61.0332 & 61.0315 & 61.0343 & 61.0288 & 61.0283 & 61.0317 & 61.0281 & 61.0324 & 61.0294 & 61.0278 & 61.0309 & 61.0248 & 61.0292 \\ 
        {\textit{Northing}} & -45.3974 & -45.3975 & -45.3976 & -45.4103 & -45.4086 & -45.4092 & -45.4092 & -45.4094 & -45.4094 & -45.4131 & -45.4125 & -45.4124 & -45.4122 & -45.4232 & -45.4229 & -45.4230 & -45.4288 & -45.4291 & -45.4291 & -45.4131 & -45.4131 & -45.4176 & -45.4177 & -45.4178 & -45.3870 & -45.3870 & -45.3870 & -45.3864 & -45.3928 & -45.3936 & -45.3958 & -45.3933 & -45.3933 & -45.3933 & -45.3969 & -45.3974 & -45.3946 & -45.3947 & -45.4322 & -45.4053 & -45.4090 & -45.4085 & -45.4094 & -45.4114 & -45.4103 & -45.4127 & -45.4164 & -45.4142 & -45.4168 & -45.4153 & -45.4148 & -45.4202 & -45.4188 & -45.4294 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{55}{l}{Major elements (wt \%)} \\
        \ce{SiO2} & 98.3 & 98.6 & 98.9 & 96.49 & 98.5 & 98.1 & 99.6 & 98.5 & 98.5 & 89.91 & 98.8 & 99.4 & 99.7 & 97.4 & 99.7 & 98.8 & 100 & 98.2 & 99.8 & 97.2 & 95.2 & 99.9 & 99.8 & 98.4 & 97 & 97.7 & 98.4 & 94.56 & 82.74 & 84.35 & 90.93 & 84.05 & 89.7 & 95.32 & 96.59 & 95.6 & 97 & 93.02 & 92.11 & 98.5 & 97.1 & 98.8 & 99.1 & 99 & 96.8 & 98.9 & 98.57 & 97.86 & 98.9 & 98.11 & 99 & 99.6 & 98.9 & 98.82 \\ 
        \ce{Al2O3} & 0.24 & 0.66 & 0.47 & 1.44 & 1.09 & 0.54 & 0.3 & 0.64 & 0.79 & 4.6 & 0.23 & 0.16 & 0.22 & 0.86 & 0.73 & 0.4 & 0.31 & 0.51 & 0.27 & 1.36 & 1.9 & 0.37 & 0.22 & 0.26 & 0.82 & 0.7 & 0.72 & 1.94 & 6.56 & 5.87 & 3.21 & 7.26 & 4.49 & 1.19 & 1.38 & 1.1 & 1.49 & 0.3 & 0.21 & 0.61 & 1.05 & 0.53 & 0.43 & 1.03 & 1.35 & 0.49 & 0.39 & 0.63 & 0.15 & 0.52 & 0.3 & 0.22 & 0.59 & 0.46 \\ 
        \ce{Fe2O3$_T^*$} & 0.21 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 0.24 & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.1 & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.7 & 0.34 & 0.25 & 0.38 & 0.13 & 0.15 & 0.24 & 0.08 & 0.2 & 0.06 & 0.29 & 0.61 & 0.1 & 0.09 & 0.11 & 0.55 & 0.58 & 0.15 & 0.73 & 0.83 & 0.74 & 0.62 & 0.63 & 0.49 & 1.44 & 0.28 & 0.98 & 0.54 & 4.34 & 7.16 & 0.16 & 0.26 & 0.09 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.32 & 0.26 & 0.08 & 0.28 & 0.08 & 0.22 & 0.21 & 0.12 & 0.21 & 0.1 \\ 
        \ce{CaO} & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.05 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.02 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.01 & 0.29 & 1.81 & 1.6 & 0.9 & 0.34 & 0.54 & 0.11 & 0.04 & 0.16 & 0.03 & 0.09 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.24 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.03 & {bdl} \\ 
        MgO & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.08 & 0.07 & 0.02 & 0.04 & 1.51 & 1.11 & 0.63 & 0.15 & 0.29 & 0.02 & {bdl} & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.03 & {bdl} \\ 
        \ce{Na2O} & 0.16 & 0.22 & 0.18 & 0.52 & 0.06 & 0.08 & 0.09 & 0.44 & 0.23 & 0.23 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.16 & 0.64 & 1.11 & 0.08 & 0.09 & 0.05 & 0.32 & 0.37 & 0.15 & 0.75 & 0.77 & 1.68 & 0.37 & 0.8 & 0.5 & 0.62 & 0.29 & 0.46 & 0.29 & 1.58 & 0.01 & 0.15 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 0.13 & 0.24 & 0.22 & 0.04 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.06 & 0.21 & 0.08 & 0.08 & 0.19 & 0.08 \\ 
        \ce{K2O} & 0.11 & 0.31 & 0.23 & 0.58 & 0.88 & 0.38 & 0.16 & 0.01 & 0.48 & 3.91 & 0.04 & 0.08 & 0.12 & 0.67 & 0.6 & 0.35 & 0.22 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.41 & 0.38 & 0.23 & 0.06 & 0.16 & 0.46 & 0.33 & 0.44 & 0.85 & 5.08 & 4.03 & 2.56 & 5.74 & 3.52 & 0.49 & 0.84 & 0.6 & 1.15 & 0.19 & 0.07 & 0.33 & 0.72 & 0.33 & 0.23 & 0.55 & 0.87 & 0.4 & 0.19 & 0.42 & 0.03 & 0.26 & 0.14 & 0.07 & 0.33 & 0.28 \\ 
        \ce{Cr2O3} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na & na & na & na & na & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} \\ 
        \ce{TiO2} & 0.01 & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.15 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.07 & 0.24 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.03 & 0.16 & 0.14 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.13 & 0.04 & 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.06 & 0.04 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.02 \\ 
        MnO & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.03 & 0.07 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.02 & {bdl} & 0.02 & 0.09 & 0.01 & 0.78 & 0.01 & 0.04 & 0.05 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} \\ 
        \ce{P2O5} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.02 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.03 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.06 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.15 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.17 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.02 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 \\ 
        SrO & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & 0.02 & 0.05 & na & na & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & na & na & 0.01 & na & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & na \\ 
        BaO & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & {bdl} & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & 0.07 & 0.05 & na & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & na & na & {bdl} & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & na \\ 
        LOI & 0.16 & 0.15 & 0.29 & 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.25 & 0.19 & 0.21 & 0.3 & 0.26 & 0.17 & 0.18 & 0.03 & 0.13 & 0.18 & 0.27 & 0.26 & 0.27 & 0.31 & 0.41 & 0.15 & 0.19 & 0.33 & 0.21 & 0.17 & 0.16 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 0.21 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.35 & 0.28 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.19 & 0.26 & 0.17 & 0.16 & 0.21 & 0.13 & 0.41 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.29 & 0.5 & 0.35 & 0.26 & 0.19 & 0.1 \\ 
        \ce{H2O+} (calc) & 0.18 & 0.17 & 0.30 & 0.43 & 0.22 & 0.32 & 0.26 & 0.21 & 0.23 & 0.37 & 0.30 & 0.20 & 0.22 & 0.04 & 0.15 & 0.21 & 0.28 & 0.28 & 0.28 & 0.35 & 0.49 & 0.16 & 0.20 & 0.34 & 0.28 & 0.24 & 0.18 & 0.58 & 0.40 & 0.30 & 0.57 & 0.66 & 0.25 & 0.46 & 0.33 & 0.62 & 0.34 & 0.74 & 0.93 & 0.21 & 0.29 & 0.18 & 0.17 & 0.23 & 0.16 & 0.44 & 0.51 & 0.43 & 0.30 & 0.52 & 0.37 & 0.27 & 0.21 & 0.11 \\ 
        Total & 99.26 & 100.16 & 100.25 & 99.91 & 100.92 & 99.61 & 100.53 & 99.96 & 100.44 & 99.98 & 99.81 & 100.18 & 100.84 & 99.26 & 101.4 & 100.12 & 100.97 & 99.66 & 100.62 & 100.33 & 99.98 & 100.86 & 100.47 & 99.35 & 99.69 & 100.14 & 100.1 & 99.94 & 99.96 & 99.92 & 99.95 & 99.96 & 99.96 & 99.84 & 99.88 & 100.34 & 100.95 & 100.35 & 100.61 & 100.02 & 99.64 & 100.07 & 100.61 & 101.24 & 99.8 & 100.57 & 99.87 & 99.71 & 99.54 & 99.89 & 100.13 & 100.39 & 100.5 & 99.88 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{55}{l}{Trace elements (ppm)} \\
        Ba & 11.7 & 60.5 & 71.8 & 66.7 & 26.7 & 24.5 & 14.7 & 2.9 & 10.1 & 66.4 & 11 & 28.3 & 14.1 & 52.1 & 42.8 & 43.1 & 36.6 & 63.2 & 14.6 & 18.2 & 72.4 & 15.9 & 7.9 & 22.7 & 96.2 & 60.7 & 35.3 & 149 & 287 & 284 & 227 & 414 & 268.5 & 617 & 321 & 576 & 401 & 59.1 & 32.6 & 29.4 & 34.7 & 20.7 & 16.4 & 34 & 56 & 32.4 & 18.5 & 30.7 & 9 & 14.2 & 17.2 & 15.9 & 13.1 & 22.8 \\ 
        Ce & 9.7 & 21.2 & 4.2 & 6.3 & 6 & 5.7 & 4.3 & 3.7 & 5.2 & 46 & 8.6 & 6 & 3 & 14 & 15 & 25.6 & 12.3 & 19 & 15.6 & 55.3 & 66.7 & 4.4 & 3.7 & 5.2 & 124 & 29.3 & 13.8 & 41.3 & 52.3 & 47.7 & 39.3 & 50.6 & 23.2 & 452 & 18.4 & 202 & 22.7 & 58.4 & 4.9 & 5.2 & 6.8 & 7.9 & 5.5 & 5.7 & 7.7 & 7.4 & 12 & 3.3 & 1.8 & 2.4 & 7.8 & 7.3 & 6.9 & 6.6 \\ 
        Cr & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & 10 & 10 & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & 10 & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & na & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & 10 & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} \\ 
        Cs & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.11 & 0.05 & {bdl} & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.05 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.11 & 0.16 & {bdl} & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.1 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.16 & 0.09 & 0.12 & 0.03 & na & 0.03 & 0.24 & 0.62 & 0.03 & {bdl} & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.02 & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 0.01 & {bdl} & 0.01 \\ 
        Dy & 0.97 & 1.99 & 0.39 & 0.68 & 0.79 & 1.25 & 0.95 & 1 & 1.29 & 2.02 & 0.64 & 0.49 & 0.32 & 1.96 & 1.73 & 0.99 & 1.33 & 2.2 & 1.63 & 3.98 & 15.8 & 1.03 & 0.63 & 2.33 & 4.83 & 2.67 & 1.08 & 1.62 & 5.35 & 4.99 & 3.8 & 5.55 & na & 6.72 & 1.94 & 14.8 & 0.92 & 2.76 & 1.21 & 0.48 & 0.77 & 0.43 & 1.57 & 0.82 & 1.81 & 0.79 & 1.64 & 0.67 & 0.47 & 0.5 & 0.8 & 0.61 & 0.33 & 0.76 \\ 
        Er & 0.56 & 1.37 & 0.31 & 0.45 & 0.49 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.63 & 0.67 & 1.15 & 0.42 & 0.35 & 0.22 & 1.14 & 0.96 & 0.72 & 0.62 & 1.09 & 0.76 & 3.15 & 13.85 & 0.63 & 0.38 & 1.49 & 2.36 & 1.75 & 0.67 & 0.77 & 2.88 & 2.94 & 2.2 & 2.08 & na & 2.64 & 1.23 & 8.54 & 0.41 & 1.56 & 0.68 & 0.33 & 0.55 & 0.29 & 0.89 & 0.51 & 1.03 & 0.6 & 1.16 & 0.47 & 0.35 & 0.39 & 0.56 & 0.33 & 0.27 & 0.47 \\ 
        Eu & 0.16 & 0.43 & 0.14 & 0.12 & 0.16 & 0.2 & 0.18 & 0.15 & 0.25 & 0.43 & 0.18 & 0.08 & 0.1 & 0.39 & 0.41 & 0.21 & 0.41 & 0.66 & 0.54 & 0.29 & 0.6 & 0.21 & 0.16 & 0.35 & 1.31 & 0.49 & 0.23 & 0.61 & 1.16 & 0.93 & 0.73 & 1.45 & na & 3.41 & 0.28 & 2.62 & 0.47 & 1.09 & 0.18 & 0.12 & 0.18 & 0.11 & 0.44 & 0.16 & 0.24 & 0.2 & 0.27 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.13 & 0.12 & 0.13 & 0.07 & 0.16 \\ 
        Ga & 0.6 & 0.9 & 0.5 & 1.6 & 0.8 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.9 & 0.9 & 5.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 2.8 & 7.4 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 1.6 & 1.2 & 0.8 & 3.3 & 6.9 & 7.7 & 3 & 8.8 & na & 3.4 & 1.8 & 3.5 & 1.5 & 0.9 & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.9 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 0.4 & 0.2 & 0.4 & {bdl} & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0.5 \\ 
        Gd & 0.98 & 2.13 & 0.63 & 0.57 & 0.83 & 1.36 & 1.15 & 0.89 & 1.49 & 2.38 & 0.9 & 0.38 & 0.47 & 1.8 & 1.76 & 0.78 & 1.88 & 2.88 & 2.32 & 3.07 & 7.6 & 1.27 & 0.85 & 2.52 & 6.67 & 2.78 & 1.15 & 2.26 & 5.95 & 5.22 & 3.97 & 7.54 & na & 13.25 & 1.72 & 15.4 & 1.62 & 4.32 & 1.04 & 0.52 & 0.76 & 0.69 & 2.69 & 0.74 & 1.57 & 0.74 & 1.79 & 0.77 & 0.48 & 0.7 & 0.83 & 0.72 & 0.31 & 0.89 \\ 
        Hf & 1 & 4.9 & 1.5 & 3 & 0.7 & 2.4 & 0.7 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 5 & 0.9 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 3.9 & 1.6 & 3 & 0.8 & 1.4 & 0.9 & 6.8 & 19.1 & 1.8 & 1.3 & 1.6 & 4.5 & 3.7 & 2.1 & 1.9 & 3 & 3.9 & 2.7 & 0.5 & na & 2.4 & 2.3 & 7.9 & 1.8 & 1.3 & 1.1 & 2.8 & 3.2 & 1.1 & 2 & 1 & 2.7 & 3.8 & 1 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.9 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        Ho & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.08 & 0.13 & 0.14 & 0.25 & 0.16 & 0.17 & 0.23 & 0.38 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.41 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0.21 & 0.36 & 0.27 & 0.85 & 3.58 & 0.18 & 0.11 & 0.47 & 0.82 & 0.52 & 0.2 & 0.23 & 0.94 & 0.95 & 0.71 & 0.87 & na & 1.03 & 0.34 & 2.71 & 0.16 & 0.48 & 0.24 & 0.12 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.26 & 0.16 & 0.36 & 0.18 & 0.34 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.16 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.15 \\ 
        La & 4.7 & 12.1 & 4.3 & 6.1 & 3.7 & 4.9 & 3.3 & 3.3 & 4.2 & 18.5 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 2.5 & 6.5 & 8.1 & 3.7 & 8.6 & 9.4 & 9.3 & 27 & 21 & 3.6 & 3.2 & 5.2 & 77.1 & 17.4 & 5.2 & 19.5 & 23.4 & 22.9 & 18.1 & 25.2 & 18.5 & 263 & 5.9 & 86.7 & 13.4 & 34.3 & 4 & 3.7 & 5.3 & 4.8 & 4.5 & 4.3 & 3.3 & 2.1 & 4.7 & 1.7 & 1.4 & 2.4 & 3.1 & 2.7 & 1.9 & 4 \\ 
        Lu & 0.08 & 0.17 & 0.04 & 0.08 & 0.07 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.06 & 0.07 & 0.19 & 0.05 & 0.05 & 0.03 & 0.17 & 0.12 & 0.13 & 0.08 & 0.1 & 0.09 & 0.49 & 2.02 & 0.07 & 0.04 & 0.16 & 0.27 & 0.21 & 0.09 & 0.15 & 0.37 & 0.47 & 0.29 & 0.13 & na & 0.24 & 0.1 & 0.91 & 0.05 & 0.27 & 0.09 & 0.06 & 0.09 & 0.03 & 0.09 & 0.06 & 0.12 & 0.1 & 0.14 & 0.11 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.1 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.06 \\ 
        Nb & 9.9 & 22.5 & 3.6 & 7.6 & 2 & 2.8 & 1.9 & 2.2 & 3.8 & 10.3 & 2.7 & 3.4 & 2.5 & 3.5 & 2.3 & 5.8 & 2 & 3.6 & 2.3 & 80.5 & 231 & 1.7 & 1.4 & 2.8 & 192 & 39.4 & 9.5 & 26.4 & 9.9 & 21.9 & 19.9 & 14.9 & 10.7 & 42.5 & 33.5 & 92.2 & 7.1 & 12.3 & 74.9 & 3.3 & 4.9 & 2.3 & 2.5 & 2.5 & 5.1 & 9 & 1.7 & 3.2 & 1.4 & 2.8 & 3.9 & 1.8 & 3.3 & 1.9 \\ 
        Nd & 3.9 & 11.6 & 3.4 & 5.6 & 3.3 & 4.6 & 3.4 & 3.7 & 4.7 & 16.3 & 3.6 & 1.3 & 2.7 & 10.2 & 12.1 & 5.4 & 10.6 & 14 & 14.1 & 19.2 & 21.8 & 3.4 & 4.1 & 8 & 56 & 14.6 & 6 & 19 & 29.2 & 27.7 & 21.2 & 32.6 & 12.7 & 174.5 & 8 & 94.3 & 16.9 & 35.6 & 5.1 & 3.1 & 4.7 & 4.4 & 6.2 & 5.3 & 3.7 & 2.7 & 5.8 & 2.1 & 1.2 & 5 & 3.7 & 2.8 & 2 & 4.3 \\ 
        Ni & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & 3.6 & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na \\ 
        Pr & 0.97 & 3.08 & 0.81 & 1.37 & 0.84 & 1.12 & 0.76 & 0.8 & 1.11 & 4.06 & 0.83 & 0.31 & 0.62 & 2.21 & 2.71 & 1.27 & 2.39 & 2.84 & 3.04 & 5.55 & 5.74 & 0.84 & 0.9 & 1.61 & 14.9 & 3.56 & 1.45 & 4.8 & 6.68 & 6.43 & 4.93 & 7 & na & 48 & 1.8 & 23.5 & 4.15 & 8.29 & 1.04 & 0.86 & 1.19 & 1.05 & 1.38 & 1.18 & 0.84 & 0.59 & 1.22 & 0.43 & 0.32 & 0.88 & 1 & 0.73 & 0.49 & 0.91 \\ 
        Rb & 3 & 5.9 & 5.4 & 11 & 8.8 & 4.7 & 2.1 & 0.3 & 7.1 & 48.3 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.9 & 9.3 & 8.5 & 5.5 & 3.4 & 6.4 & 0.7 & 34.3 & 31.2 & 3 & 1 & 2.4 & 8.9 & 7.2 & 8.2 & 13.2 & 74.7 & 67.9 & 41.5 & 79.9 & na & 11.7 & 25.9 & 28.9 & 14.6 & 3.5 & 1.6 & 4.2 & 10.6 & 4 & 3.4 & 6.8 & 12.5 & 5.5 & 3.4 & 5.8 & 0.7 & 3.8 & 2.3 & 1.2 & 4.6 & 3.5 \\ 
        Sc & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & {bdl} & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na & na \\ 
        Sm & 0.8 & 2.37 & 0.64 & 0.83 & 0.65 & 0.81 & 0.8 & 0.73 & 1.18 & 3.22 & 0.81 & 0.37 & 0.59 & 1.98 & 2.27 & 1.04 & 2.35 & 3.34 & 2.97 & 3.78 & 5.97 & 0.98 & 0.9 & 1.64 & 9.21 & 2.88 & 1.21 & 3.13 & 5.84 & 5.26 & 4.04 & 7.15 & {bdl} & 22 & 1.78 & 18.45 & 2.8 & 5.96 & 1.04 & 0.63 & 0.97 & 0.81 & 1.88 & 0.92 & 0.94 & 0.75 & 1.16 & 0.54 & 0.34 & 0.66 & 0.86 & 0.59 & 0.38 & 0.76 \\ 
        Sn & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & {bdl} & 1 & 1 & {bdl} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 12 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & na & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & {bdl} & 1 & {bdl} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
        Sr & 13 & 17 & 53.4 & 33.1 & 4.3 & 6 & 3.1 & 7.2 & 4.5 & 37.4 & 6.2 & 8.5 & 3.4 & 11.1 & 6.5 & 11.2 & 3.5 & 5.2 & 6.7 & 8.3 & 17.3 & 4.7 & 3 & 3.9 & 39.1 & 34.4 & 7.4 & 181.5 & 99.8 & 104 & 90.1 & 137 & 164 & 71.1 & 34.2 & 122 & 329 & 36.7 & 3.2 & 3.9 & 4 & 3.2 & 23.9 & 6.4 & 17.1 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 3.1 & 7.8 & 3.9 & 7.1 & 7.9 & 5.3 \\ 
        Ta & 0.9 & 1.7 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0.8 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 4.8 & 15.1 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 3.1 & 1.3 & 0.8 & 2.3 & 0.7 & 1.6 & 1.3 & 0.6 & na & 1.3 & 1.7 & 4.2 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 2.2 & 0.8 & 0.5 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.6 \\ 
        Tb & 0.13 & 0.31 & 0.07 & 0.09 & 0.1 & 0.19 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 0.21 & 0.3 & 0.12 & 0.06 & 0.04 & 0.28 & 0.24 & 0.12 & 0.23 & 0.37 & 0.29 & 0.54 & 1.88 & 0.15 & 0.1 & 0.34 & 0.9 & 0.4 & 0.18 & 0.3 & 0.85 & 0.74 & 0.59 & 0.96 & na & 1.36 & 0.28 & 2.25 & 0.18 & 0.48 & 0.16 & 0.09 & 0.13 & 0.07 & 0.3 & 0.13 & 0.26 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.1 & 0.08 & 0.08 & 0.11 & 0.09 & 0.06 & 0.11 \\ 
        Th & 1.67 & 4.73 & 0.9 & 1.52 & 1.05 & 1.25 & 0.92 & 0.77 & 1.77 & 8.3 & 0.84 & 0.69 & 0.5 & 1.34 & 1.19 & 1.33 & 1.3 & 1.47 & 1.47 & 15.55 & 103 & 0.76 & 0.66 & 1 & 4.68 & 5.56 & 2 & 0.96 & 2.44 & 3.23 & 2.67 & 1.02 & {bdl} & 2 & 2.4 & 27.1 & 0.61 & 1.1 & 1.06 & 0.96 & 1.48 & 1.05 & 1.49 & 1.24 & 1.83 & 1.94 & 1 & 5.38 & 0.43 & 0.67 & 2.37 & 0.94 & 1.14 & 0.81 \\ 
        Tm & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.04 & 0.07 & 0.04 & 0.08 & 0.06 & 0.06 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.04 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.16 & 0.12 & 0.11 & 0.08 & 0.13 & 0.09 & 0.53 & 2.22 & 0.07 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.31 & 0.24 & 0.09 & 0.09 & 0.4 & 0.43 & 0.31 & 0.23 & na & 0.3 & 0.13 & 1.16 & 0.06 & 0.21 & 0.08 & 0.07 & 0.09 & 0.02 & 0.12 & 0.08 & 0.15 & 0.11 & 0.12 & 0.06 & 0.05 & 0.04 & 0.08 & 0.06 & 0.04 & 0.07 \\ 
        U & 0.4 & 1.1 & 0.19 & 0.35 & 0.18 & 0.28 & 0.19 & 0.15 & 0.21 & 0.66 & 0.26 & 0.2 & 0.19 & 0.37 & 0.26 & 0.3 & 0.24 & 0.37 & 0.24 & 3.43 & 7.64 & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.35 & 9.87 & 1.48 & 0.5 & 0.11 & 0.42 & 0.49 & 0.49 & 0.17 & 2 & 1.64 & 0.84 & 2.77 & 0.12 & 0.19 & 0.48 & 0.29 & 0.32 & 0.2 & 0.48 & 0.24 & 0.36 & 0.41 & 0.24 & 0.22 & 0.14 & 0.15 & 0.17 & 0.18 & 0.18 & 0.23 \\ 
        V & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 9 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 9 & {bdl} & 7 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 5 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 5 & 6 & {bdl} & 8 & {bdl} & 5 & 6 & 10 & na & 14 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 15 & 27 & {bdl} & {bdl} & 5 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 6 & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} \\ 
        Y & 6.5 & 12.9 & 2.6 & 3.7 & 4.4 & 8.3 & 5.7 & 5.5 & 7 & 10.1 & 3.6 & 3.7 & 1.8 & 11.5 & 9.1 & 6.3 & 6.1 & 10 & 7.5 & 23.4 & 88.8 & 6.2 & 3.2 & 15.1 & 25.4 & 18.2 & 6 & 5.6 & 25.4 & 23.8 & 19 & 20 & 9.5 & 30 & 9.6 & 79.8 & 4.6 & 12.5 & 5.7 & 3.2 & 5 & 2.8 & 9 & 5 & 11.1 & 5.6 & 10.8 & 3.7 & 3.4 & 3 & 4.6 & 3.4 & 1.8 & 4 \\ 
        Yb & 0.69 & 1.38 & 0.38 & 0.53 & 0.45 & 0.77 & 0.49 & 0.53 & 0.54 & 1.39 & 0.39 & 0.36 & 0.27 & 1.23 & 0.81 & 0.97 & 0.6 & 0.9 & 0.81 & 3.72 & 16.2 & 0.56 & 0.32 & 1.25 & 2.27 & 1.58 & 0.71 & 0.9 & 2.69 & 3.08 & 2.29 & 1.12 & na & 1.86 & 1 & 7.77 & 0.37 & 1.75 & 0.66 & 0.49 & 0.64 & 0.29 & 0.68 & 0.45 & 1.01 & 0.78 & 0.9 & 0.72 & 0.31 & 0.41 & 0.68 & 0.39 & 0.28 & 0.48 \\ 
        Zr & 40 & 239 & 61 & 115 & 22 & 93 & 25 & 50 & 61 & 189 & 29 & 19 & 21 & 150 & 54 & 140 & 27 & 56 & 31 & 357 & 1010 & 67 & 43 & 59 & 194 & 134 & 72 & 60 & 111 & 134 & 104 & 15 & 13.3 & 96 & 93 & 433 & 80 & 42 & 39 & 119 & 136 & 40 & 85 & 39 & 118 & 174 & 39 & 23 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 30 & 38 & 40 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
    \item[]Category abbreviations: D(x)EF = Eriksfjord fenite related to select Igaliku Dyke Swarm bodies numbered as appropriate, EF = Eriksfjord fenite, EU = unaltered Eriksfjord arenite; Abbreviations for laboratories as in Tables \ref{AppB-XRF-ICP-BVC, AppB-XRF-STA, AppB-ICP-ALS}), if second abb. is not given, both major and trace data come from the same lab; Distance as measured from the mapped boundary of the Illerfissalik 
    bdl = below detection limit, na = not analysed, T denotes \ce{Fe^{3+}} as Total Fe; easting-northing in dec. deg. format
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: `longtable` and related packages can only split a table that it too tall, not a table that is too wide for a page. The probably most simple approach would involve manually splitting the table at the desired column. For an automated approach, you might be interested in [Column-wise break of extra wide tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93808/134144).

Answer (score 1):

Since your table is not only extremely wide but also quite tall, I suggest using portrait pages instead of landscape pages. If you slightly rearrange the column headers, you can fit a total of 12 samples on a single page while also keeping the font size at `\footnotesize`  as opposed to `\tiny`.

As a starting point, here is the first page of the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=25mm, bmargin=25mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Whole-rock geochemistry data for the Eriksfjord Group arenites and its fenite}
    \label{AppB-ICP-ALS}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{4pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{6pt}}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{12}{S[table-format=-3.2]}}
        \toprule    
        {\textit{Sample}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{KS19-15-QT} & {KSL} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{KS19-15-QT} & {KSL} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{KS19-6-QT}\\ 
        \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-10} \cmidrule{12-13}
                                & {3.4}  & {3.5}  & {3.6}  & {15-1a}& {2.1}  & {2.2}  & {2.3}  & {2.9}  & {2.10} &  {T3-04a}  & {1.1}  & {1.2} \\ 
        \midrule
        {\textit{Analysed at}}  & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {ALS}  & {BVC/ALS} & {ALS}  & {ALS}  \\ 
        {\textit{Category}}     & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF}    & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF} & {D1EF}    & {D1EF} & {D1EF} \\ 
        {\textit{Distance (m)}} & {450}  & {450}  & {450}  & {1130}    & {1210} & {1210} & {1210} & {1210} & {1210} & {1310}    & {1405} & {1405} \\ 
        \midrule
        {\textit{Easting}}  & 61.0345  & 61.0346  & 61.0346  & 61.0361  & 61.0309  & 61.0308  & 61.0309  & 61.0312  & 61.0311  & 61.0342  & 61.0300  & 61.0299\\ 
        {\textit{Northing}} & -45.3974 & -45.3975 & -45.3976 & -45.4103 & -45.4086 & -45.4092 & -45.4092 & -45.4094 & -45.4094 & -45.4131 & -45.4125 & -45.4124 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{Major elements (wt \%)} \\
        \ce{SiO2}        & 98.3  & 98.6   & 98.9   & 96.49 & 98.5   & 98.1  & 99.6   & 98.5  & 98.5   & 89.91 & 98.8  & 99.4   \\ 
        \ce{Al2O3}       & 0.24  & 0.66   & 0.47   & 1.44  & 1.09   & 0.54  & 0.3    & 0.64  & 0.79   & 4.6   & 0.23  & 0.16   \\ 
        \ce{Fe2O3$_T^*$} & 0.21  & 0.14   & 0.13   & 0.24  & 0.14   & 0.16  & 0.1    & 0.14  & 0.16   & 0.7   & 0.34  & 0.25   \\ 
        \ce{CaO}         & 0.04  & 0.01   & 0.01   & 0.09  & 0.01   & {bdl} & {bdl}  & 0.01  & 0.02   & 0.05  & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ 
        MgO              & 0.02  & 0.01   & 0.01   & 0.04  & 0.01   & 0.01  & 0.01   & 0.01  & 0.02   & 0.03  & 0.01  & 0.01   \\ \addlinespace
        \ce{Na2O}        & 0.16  & 0.22   & 0.18   & 0.52  & 0.06   & 0.08  & 0.09   & 0.44  & 0.23   & 0.23  & 0.12  & 0.1    \\ 
        \ce{K2O}         & 0.11  & 0.31   & 0.23   & 0.58  & 0.88   & 0.38  & 0.16   & 0.01  & 0.48   & 3.91  & 0.04  & 0.08   \\ 
        \ce{Cr2O3}       & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ 
        \ce{TiO2}        & 0.01  & 0.04   & 0.02   & 0.06  & 0.03   & 0.04  & 0.02   & 0.02  & 0.03   & 0.15  & 0.01  & 0.01   \\ 
        MnO              & 0.01  & 0.01   & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ \addlinespace
        \ce{P2O5}        & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl}  & 0.02  & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & 0.03  & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ 
        SrO              & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl}  & na    & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & na    & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ 
        BaO              & {bdl} & 0.01   & 0.01   & na    & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & {bdl} & {bdl}  & na    & {bdl} & {bdl}  \\ 
        LOI              & 0.16  & 0.15   & 0.29   & 0.4   & 0.2    & 0.3   & 0.25   & 0.19  & 0.21   & 0.3   & 0.26  & 0.17   \\ 
        \ce{H2O+} (calc) & 0.18  & 0.17   & 0.30   & 0.43  & 0.22   & 0.32  & 0.26   & 0.21  & 0.23   & 0.37  & 0.30  & 0.20   \\ \addlinespace 
        Total            & 99.26 & 100.16 & 100.25 & 99.91 & 100.92 & 99.61 & 100.53 & 99.96 & 100.44 & 99.98 & 99.81 & 100.18 \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{12}{l}{Trace elements (ppm)} \\
        Ba & 11.7  & 60.5  & 71.8  & 66.7  & 26.7  & 24.5  & 14.7  & 2.9   & 10.1  & 66.4  & 11    & 28.3  \\ 
        Ce & 9.7   & 21.2  & 4.2   & 6.3   & 6     & 5.7   & 4.3   & 3.7   & 5.2   & 46    & 8.6   & 6     \\ 
        Cr & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10    & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 10    & {bdl} & 10    & 10    \\ 
        Cs & 0.02  & 0.01  & 0.02  & 0.02  & {bdl} & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.01  & 0.11  & 0.05  & {bdl} \\ 
        Dy & 0.97  & 1.99  & 0.39  & 0.68  & 0.79  & 1.25  & 0.95  & 1     & 1.29  & 2.02  & 0.64  & 0.49  \\ \addlinespace
        Er & 0.56  & 1.37  & 0.31  & 0.45  & 0.49  & 0.89  & 0.49  & 0.63  & 0.67  & 1.15  & 0.42  & 0.35  \\ 
        Eu & 0.16  & 0.43  & 0.14  & 0.12  & 0.16  & 0.2   & 0.18  & 0.15  & 0.25  & 0.43  & 0.18  & 0.08  \\ 
        Ga & 0.6   & 0.9   & 0.5   & 1.6   & 0.8   & 0.5   & 0.5   & 0.9   & 0.9   & 5.1   & 0.2   & 0.3   \\  
        Gd & 0.98  & 2.13  & 0.63  & 0.57  & 0.83  & 1.36  & 1.15  & 0.89  & 1.49  & 2.38  & 0.9   & 0.38  \\ 
        Hf & 1     & 4.9   & 1.5   & 3     & 0.7   & 2.4   & 0.7   & 1.4   & 1.5   & 5     & 0.9   & 0.7   \\  \addlinespace
        Ho & 0.2   & 0.4   & 0.08  & 0.13  & 0.14  & 0.25  & 0.16  & 0.17  & 0.23  & 0.38  & 0.12  & 0.11  \\ 
        La & 4.7   & 12.1  & 4.3   & 6.1   & 3.7   & 4.9   & 3.3   & 3.3   & 4.2   & 18.5  & 3.6   & 1.4   \\  
        Lu & 0.08  & 0.17  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.07  & 0.1   & 0.05  & 0.06  & 0.07  & 0.19  & 0.05  & 0.05  \\ 
        Nb & 9.9   & 22.5  & 3.6   & 7.6   & 2     & 2.8   & 1.9   & 2.2   & 3.8   & 10.3  & 2.7   & 3.4   \\ 
        Nd & 3.9   & 11.6  & 3.4   & 5.6   & 3.3   & 4.6   & 3.4   & 3.7   & 4.7   & 16.3  & 3.6   & 1.3   \\ \addlinespace
        Ni & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  \\ 
        Pr & 0.97  & 3.08  & 0.81  & 1.37  & 0.84  & 1.12  & 0.76  & 0.8   & 1.11  & 4.06  & 0.83  & 0.31  \\ 
        Rb & 3     & 5.9   & 5.4   & 11    & 8.8   & 4.7   & 2.1   & 0.3   & 7.1   & 48.3  & 1.1   & 1.3   \\ 
        Sc & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  & {na}  \\ 
        Sm & 0.8   & 2.37  & 0.64  & 0.83  & 0.65  & 0.81  & 0.8   & 0.73  & 1.18  & 3.22  & 0.81  & 0.37  \\ \addlinespace
        Sn & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & {bdl} & 1     & 1     & {bdl} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     \\ 
        Sr & 13    & 17    & 53.4  & 33.1  & 4.3   & 6     & 3.1   & 7.2   & 4.5   & 37.4  & 6.2   & 8.5   \\ 
        Ta & 0.9   & 1.7   & 0.6   & 0.6   & 0.6   & 0.6   & 0.5   & 0.4   & 0.6   & 0.8   & 0.8   & 0.6   \\ 
        Tb & 0.13  & 0.31  & 0.07  & 0.09  & 0.1   & 0.19  & 0.14  & 0.13  & 0.21  & 0.3   & 0.12  & 0.06  \\ 
        Th & 1.67  & 4.73  & 0.9   & 1.52  & 1.05  & 1.25  & 0.92  & 0.77  & 1.77  & 8.3   & 0.84  & 0.69  \\ \addlinespace
        Tm & 0.07  & 0.17  & 0.04  & 0.07  & 0.04  & 0.08  & 0.06  & 0.06  & 0.07  & 0.17  & 0.04  & 0.04  \\ 
        U  & 0.4   & 1.1   & 0.19  & 0.35  & 0.18  & 0.28  & 0.19  & 0.15  & 0.21  & 0.66  & 0.26  & 0.2   \\ 
        V  & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 9     & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & {bdl} & 9     & {bdl} & 7     \\ 
        Y & 6.5    & 12.9  & 2.6   & 3.7   & 4.4   & 8.3   & 5.7   & 5.5   & 7     & 10.1  & 3.6   & 3.7   \\ 
        Yb & 0.69  & 1.38  & 0.38  & 0.53  & 0.45  & 0.77  & 0.49  & 0.53  & 0.54  & 1.39  & 0.39  & 0.36  \\ 
        Zr & 40    & 239   & 61    & 115   & 22    & 93    & 25    & 50    & 61    & 189   & 29    & 19    \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize\setlength\labelsep{0pt}
    \item[]Category abbreviations: D(x)EF = Eriksfjord fenite related to select Igaliku Dyke Swarm bodies numbered as appropriate, EF = Eriksfjord fenite, EU = unaltered Eriksfjord arenite; Abbreviations for laboratories as in Tables \ref{AppB-XRF-ICP-BVC, AppB-XRF-STA, AppB-ICP-ALS}), if second abb. is not given, both major and trace data come from the same lab; Distance as measured from the mapped boundary of the Illerfissalik 
    bdl = below detection limit, na = not analysed, T denotes \ce{Fe^{3+}} as Total Fe; easting-northing in dec. deg. format
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm so assuming this is based on suggestion from the comment.. would it make sense to combine this method with `pdflscape` and fit more columns in that way by rotating the page instead of the table float? Im just concerned that large tables with lots of columns will take up a LOT of paper volume once printed.

Comment: Also I was going to ask, is there a quick way to make entries in a chosen row text type without having to manually wrap the contents in brackets? Specifically referring to the 'Distance' row after your adjustment. I was wondering if there's an easy workaround as I'd actually like to make GPS coordinates not round to 2dp as well but `siunitx` configuration currently forces it to be as is.

Comment: @Wolfe79: You could use a landscape oriented page, but your table is comparably tall, so it will pnly fit onto a landscape page if you use a `\tiny` font size. Which is quite hard to read. With the current setup, the entire table should fit onto 5 pages. Regarding `siunitx`: not that I'm awar of.