# My table is too wide to fit in landscape mode, but its height is small

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, landscape

```
\begin{tabular}{ c | c  *{102}{c}  }
        \toprule
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Domain} & \multicolumn{16}{c}{ABC} &
        \multicolumn{10}{c}{DEF} &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{CHIT} &  \multicolumn{18}{c}{XYZ} & \multicolumn{52}{c}{UVW} \\
        \cmidrule(r{4pt}){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-18}  \cmidrule(l){19-28}  \cmidrule(l){29-34}  \cmidrule(l){35-52} \cmidrule(l){53-104} 
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{References} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 &  17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 &  27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 &  57 & 58 & 59 & 60 & 61 & 62 & 63 & 64 & 65 & 66 &  67 & 68 & 69 & 70 & 71 & 72 & 73 & 74 & 75 & 76 & 77 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 & 84 & 85 & 86 & 87 & 88 & 89 & 90 & 91 & 92 &93 & 94 & 95 & 96 & 97 & 98 & 99 &100 & 101 & 102\\
        \midrule
        
        %\raisebox{1.5ex}{Criteria}
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Criteria}}}& A & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
        
         & B & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
         
         & C & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark  \\
         
        & D & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
        
         & E & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
        \bottomrule
        
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Your code is both badly formated and incomplete. Always provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) with proper formatting. Thank you.

Comment: See David's answer to [Column-wise break of extra wide tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93808/110998). Your table is too wide by far, so you have to break it horizontally. Otherwise one could tweak the inter-column space and similar things, but this will not help in your case.

Comment: I want to fit my table on a single page using. For that, I tried landscape to fit the table on a single page and used \tiny to small the table size, but my table is still out of the page. So, now I am looking to break the table columns automatically.

Comment: Thank you for you replies

Comment: 104 columns?? do you expect anyone to read the table?

Comment: It's just a simple table for the quality assessment of papers in a SLR.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Where is `sidewaystable` defined? Where are many of your other macros defined? Not being able to process your code extract, could you exchange the rows and columns? What is a SLR?