# Breaking tables both vertically and horizontally

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking

I know that one can use `longtable` for page-breaking vertically long tables. I have also seen [Column-wise break of extra wide tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables), which shows how to break a wide table horizontally.

How do I combine these two, or otherwise break a table first horizontally, then vertically?

I am fine with entering the table data either column-wise or row-wise.

Comment: it's hard to imagine any way to automatically find a good way to interleave the pieces. I would just spend a bit of time with regex replace in your editor to re-arrange the data so it fits the page width.

Comment: I could manually create the effect by splitting into multiple tables and breaking them in one direction only, yes. I was just hoping there could be an automatic method.

Comment: To clarify, I am trying to typeset transport (rail/bus) timetables, which have one column per departure (train/bus) and one row per stations. Long routes with many departures necessarily have tables that are both long and wide.