Is there any way to automatically split too wide table on two pages (side by side; without rotating)?
I need to break too wide table on two pages (portrait orientation). Is there any way to do this automatically in LaTeX?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables/93810#93810

@DavidCarlisle Thank you! It give some useful clues for my question. What should I do with my question?

@JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, but your suggestion deals with too long table. My question is about too wide table.

If you can create a wide table (up to 2\textwidth) with a gap in the center, you can split in into two halves using adjustbox.  The gap placement is critical.

If the linked question only partially answers your question, you are welcome to edit your question and provide a minimal working example that shows what you tried so far and where you got stuck. On this site, it is always recommended to show a compilable code snippet and concretely state where the problem is in order to get quick and on-spot help.
