# How can I make the columns in this longtable narrow so the table looks nicer

Tags: tables

I have made the following longtable thanks to the help of this forum and other documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.01in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\centering
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{7}{l} }
  \caption{Deleted Genes in Claudin-low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 3.3447e-37 \\

2 & A26C2 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18623364 & 18654942 & 4.3278e-15 \\

3 & A26C3 & ANKRD26-like family C, member 3 & 22q11.1 & 22 & 14636331 & 14667937 & 1.4147e-06 \\

4 & ACAA2 & acetyl-coenzyme A acyltransferase 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 45563871 & 45594249 & 0.013247 \\

5 & ACOT1 & acyl-CoA thioesterase 1 & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73073680 & 73080251 & 0.0010389 \\

6 & ACOT2 & peroxisomal long-chain acyl-coA thioesterase & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73105524 & 73112112 & 0.0010389 \\

7 & ACTB & beta actin & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5533304 & 5536758 & 0.047191 \\

8 & ADNP2 & ADNP homeobox 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 75967902 & 75999219 & 0.013247 \\

9 & ALPK2 & heart alpha-kinase & 18q23 & 18 & 54299461 & 54447169 & 0.013247 \\

10 & AMZ1 & archaelysin family metallopeptidase 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2685688 & 2721595 & 0.047191 \\

11 & ANKRD20A1 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A1 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67559660 & 3.4893e-07 \\

12 & ANKRD20A2 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A2 & 9p11.2 & 9 & 43080420 & 43123540 & 6.0142e-10 \\

13 & ANKRD20A3 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A3 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67560113 & 3.4893e-07 \\

14 & ANKRD20A4 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A4 & 9q12 & 9 & 68671800 & 68714929 & 6.1556e-08 \\

15 & ANKRD36B & ankyrin repeat domain 36B & 2q11.2 & 2 & 97487692 & 97572761 & 0.0040168 \\

16 & ANXA8 & annexin A8 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577989 & 46594128 & 1.9688e-14 \\

17 & ANXA8L1 & annexin A8-like 1 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577994 & 46594046 & 1.9688e-14 \\

18 & APC & adenomatous polyposis coli & 5q22.2 & 5 & 112101482 & 112209835 & 0.00017869 \\

19 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.7782e-08 \\

20 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform b & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

21 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform a & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

22 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform a & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6905712 & 0.054621 \\

23 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform b & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6888720 & 0.054621 \\

24 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41772521 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

25 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41732689 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

26 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41949383 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

27 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41985437 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

28 & ATP5A1 & ATP synthase, H+ transporting, mitochondrial F1 & 18q23 & 18 & 41918107 & 41938197 & 0.013247 \\

29 & ATP8B1 & ATPase, class I, type 8B, member 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 53464656 & 53550037 & 0.013247 \\

30 & ATP9B & ATPase, class II, type 9B & 18q23 & 18 & 74930384 & 75239270 & 0.013247 \\

31 & BAGE & B melanoma antigen & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10079666 & 10120808 & 8.6688e-14 \\

32 & BAGE2 & B melanoma antigen family, member 2 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

33 & BAGE3 & B melanoma antigen family, member 3 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

34 & BAGE4 & B melanoma antigen family, member 4 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

35 & BAGE5 & B melanoma antigen family, member 5 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

36 & BAHCC1 & BAH domain and coiled-coil containing 1 & 17q25.3 & 17 & 76988134 & 77047953 & 2.5467e-21 \\

37 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 beta isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 59136166 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

38 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 alpha isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 58941558 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

39 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform g & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

40 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform a & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

41 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform d & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

42 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform c & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

43 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform b & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

44 & C16orf14 & hypothetical protein LOC84331 & 16p13.3 & 16 & 631849 & 638475 & 0.053767 \\

45 & C18orf22 & hypothetical protein LOC79863 & 18q23 & 18 & 75895345 & 75907377 & 0.013247 \\

46 & C18orf24 & spindle and KT associated 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 46155389 & 46174536 & 0.013247 \\

47 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform b & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

48 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform a & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

49 & C18orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC284254 & 18q23 & 18 & 50409387 & 50417722 & 0.013247 \\

50 & C18orf32 & hypothetical protein LOC497661 & 18q23 & 18 & 45262027 & 45267599 & 0.013247 \\

51 & C18orf51 & hypothetical protein LOC125704 & 18q23 & 18 & 70253942 & 70276159 & 0.013247 \\

52 & C18orf54 & hypothetical protein LOC162681 & 18q23 & 18 & 50139168 & 50162381 & 0.013247 \\

53 & C18orf55 & hypothetical protein LOC29090 & 18q23 & 18 & 69966725 & 69977184 & 0.013247 \\

54 & C18orf62 & hypothetical protein LOC284274 & 18q23 & 18 & 71250814 & 71268577 & 0.013247 \\

55 & C7orf20 & hypothetical protein LOC51608 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 882716 & 902597 & 0.047191 \\

56 & C7orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC79034 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6596439 & 6614880 & 0.047191 \\

57 & C7orf27 & hypothetical protein LOC221927 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2544038 & 2561672 & 0.047191 \\

58 & C7orf28A & hypothetical protein LOC51622 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5904866 & 5932129 & 0.047191 \\

59 & C7orf28B & hypothetical protein LOC221960 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6805096 & 6832386 & 0.047191 \\

60 & C7orf50 & hypothetical protein LOC84310 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 1003167 & 1144402 & 0.047191 \\

61 & C9orf167 & hypothetical protein LOC54863 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139292100 & 139296914 & 9.5724e-06 \\

62 & CACNA1C & calcium channel, voltage-dependent, L type, & 12p13.33 & 12 & 2032724 & 2677376 & 7.1656e-06 \\

63 & CARD11 & caspase recruitment domain family, member 11 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2912294 & 3050105 & 0.047191 \\

64 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 4 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41718925 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

65 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 1 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

66 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 2 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

67 & CBLN2 & cerebellin 2 precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 68354894 & 68362542 & 0.013247 \\

68 & CBWD3 & COBW domain containing 3 & 9q12 & 9 & 70046658 & 70104752 & 6.1556e-08 \\

69 & CBWD5 & COBW domain containing 5 & 9q12 & 9 & 69671823 & 69729991 & 6.1556e-08 \\

70 & CBWD6 & COBW domain containing 6 & 9q12 & 9 & 68494357 & 68552413 & 6.1556e-08 \\

71 & CCBE1 & collagen and calcium binding EGF domains 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 55252126 & 55515570 & 0.013247 \\

72 & CCDC102B & coiled-coil domain containing 102B & 18q23 & 18 & 64533470 & 64873406 & 0.013247 \\

73 & CCDC11 & coiled-coil domain containing 11 & 18q23 & 18 & 46007561 & 46046863 & 0.013247 \\

74 & CCDC125 & coiled-coil domain containing 125 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68612274 & 68652166 & 9.8166e-07 \\

75 & CCDC29 & coiled-coil domain containing 29 & 9q12 & 9 & 68715487 & 68738681 & 6.1556e-08 \\

76 & CCDC5 & coiled-coil domain containing 5 (spindle & 18q23 & 18 & 41938322 & 41962297 & 0.013247 \\

77 & CCDC68 & coiled-coil domain containing 68 & 18q23 & 18 & 50719790 & 50777635 & 0.013247 \\

78 & CCNB1 & cyclin B1 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68498668 & 68509826 & 9.8166e-07 \\

79 & CD226 & CD226 molecule precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 65681172 & 65775212 & 0.013247 \\

80 & CDH19 & cadherin 19, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 62322300 & 62422196 & 0.013247 \\

81 & CDH20 & cadherin 20, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 57308754 & 57373345 & 0.013247 \\

82 & CDH7 & cadherin 7, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 61569136 & 61699154 & 0.013247 \\

83 & CDK7 & cyclin-dependent kinase 7 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68566377 & 68609013 & 9.8166e-07 \\

84 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

85 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 3 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

86 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 4 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21984490 & 2.3804e-08 \\

87 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 2 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

88 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

89 & CDT1 & omatin licensing and DNA replication factor & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87397686 & 87403167 & 8.6264e-05 \\

90 & CENPH & centromere protein H & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68521130 & 68541940 & 9.8166e-07 \\

91 & CENTA1 & centaurin, alpha 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 904065 & 960793 & 0.047191 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I you run the code, you will see that text doesn't fit nicely, but there is a lot of white space. I was wondering if there is a way to adjust the amount of white space so they columns fit nicely? I would like my margins to be larger than 0.01 inch. Thank you!

Comment: Your table doesn't have much whitespace in my opinion.  See (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44221/is-there-something-like-sidewayslongtable) for information on rotating your table to landscape so it fits better.

Comment: @James Thank you very much! I used the pdflscape package, and it works really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `caption`, `makecell`, `siunitx`, `booktabs` and `ltablex`, you can have a  better looking table. The latter package brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. This allows to have wider margins. I also added with `makecell` some vertical padding to the rows, and a common formatting of column heads:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell, booktabs, caption}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

\begin{document}

{\makegapedcells\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r lXl S[table-format=2]*{2}{S[table-format=9]}S[table-format=1.4e-2] }
    \caption{Deleted Genes in Claudin-low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
    \toprule
       & \thead{Gene} & \thead{Description} & {\thead{Cytoband}} & {\thead{Chr }} & {\thead{Start}} & {\thead{End}} & {\thead{qValue}} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
    \toprule
       & \thead{Gene} & \thead{Description} & {\thead{Cytoband}} & {\thead{Chr}} & {\thead{Start}} & {\thead{End}} & {\thead{qValue}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 3.3447e-37 \\

    2 & A26C2 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18623364 & 18654942 & 4.3278e-15 \\

    3 & A26C3 & ANKRD26-like family C, member 3 & 22q11.1 & 22 & 14636331 & 14667937 & 1.4147e-06 \\

    4 & ACAA2 & acetyl-coenzyme A acyltransferase 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 45563871 & 45594249 & 0.013247 \\

    5 & ACOT1 & acyl-CoA thioesterase 1 & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73073680 & 73080251 & 0.0010389 \\

    6 & ACOT2 & peroxisomal long-chain acyl-coA thioesterase & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73105524 & 73112112 & 0.0010389 \\

    7 & ACTB & beta actin & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5533304 & 5536758 & 0.047191 \\

    8 & ADNP2 & ADNP homeobox 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 75967902 & 75999219 & 0.013247 \\

    9 & ALPK2 & heart alpha-kinase & 18q23 & 18 & 54299461 & 54447169 & 0.013247 \\

    10 & AMZ1 & archaelysin family metallopeptidase 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2685688 & 2721595 & 0.047191 \\

    11 & ANKRD20A1 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A1 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67559660 & 3.4893e-07 \\

    12 & ANKRD20A2 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A2 & 9p11.2 & 9 & 43080420 & 43123540 & 6.0142e-10 \\

    13 & ANKRD20A3 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A3 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67560113 & 3.4893e-07 \\

    14 & ANKRD20A4 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A4 & 9q12 & 9 & 68671800 & 68714929 & 6.1556e-08 \\

    15 & ANKRD36B & ankyrin repeat domain 36B & 2q11.2 & 2 & 97487692 & 97572761 & 0.0040168 \\

    16 & ANXA8 & annexin A8 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577989 & 46594128 & 1.9688e-14 \\

    17 & ANXA8L1 & annexin A8-like 1 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577994 & 46594046 & 1.9688e-14 \\

    18 & APC & adenomatous polyposis coli & 5q22.2 & 5 & 112101482 & 112209835 & 0.00017869 \\

    19 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.7782e-08 \\

    20 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform b & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

    21 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform a & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

    22 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform a & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6905712 & 0.054621 \\

    23 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform b & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6888720 & 0.054621 \\

    24 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41772521 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

    25 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41732689 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

    26 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41949383 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

    27 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41985437 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

    28 & ATP5A1 & ATP synthase, H+ transporting, mitochondrial F1 & 18q23 & 18 & 41918107 & 41938197 & 0.013247 \\

    29 & ATP8B1 & ATPase, class I, type 8B, member 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 53464656 & 53550037 & 0.013247 \\

    30 & ATP9B & ATPase, class II, type 9B & 18q23 & 18 & 74930384 & 75239270 & 0.013247 \\

    31 & BAGE & B melanoma antigen & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10079666 & 10120808 & 8.6688e-14 \\

    32 & BAGE2 & B melanoma antigen family, member 2 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

    33 & BAGE3 & B melanoma antigen family, member 3 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

    34 & BAGE4 & B melanoma antigen family, member 4 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

    35 & BAGE5 & B melanoma antigen family, member 5 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

    36 & BAHCC1 & BAH domain and coiled-coil containing 1 & 17q25.3 & 17 & 76988134 & 77047953 & 2.5467e-21 \\

    37 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 beta isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 59136166 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

    38 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 alpha isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 58941558 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

    39 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform g & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

    40 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform a & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

    41 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform d & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

    42 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform c & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

    43 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform b & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

    44 & C16orf14 & hypothetical protein LOC84331 & 16p13.3 & 16 & 631849 & 638475 & 0.053767 \\

    45 & C18orf22 & hypothetical protein LOC79863 & 18q23 & 18 & 75895345 & 75907377 & 0.013247 \\

    46 & C18orf24 & spindle and KT associated 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 46155389 & 46174536 & 0.013247 \\

    47 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform b & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

    48 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform a & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

    49 & C18orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC284254 & 18q23 & 18 & 50409387 & 50417722 & 0.013247 \\

    50 & C18orf32 & hypothetical protein LOC497661 & 18q23 & 18 & 45262027 & 45267599 & 0.013247 \\

    51 & C18orf51 & hypothetical protein LOC125704 & 18q23 & 18 & 70253942 & 70276159 & 0.013247 \\

    52 & C18orf54 & hypothetical protein LOC162681 & 18q23 & 18 & 50139168 & 50162381 & 0.013247 \\

    53 & C18orf55 & hypothetical protein LOC29090 & 18q23 & 18 & 69966725 & 69977184 & 0.013247 \\

    54 & C18orf62 & hypothetical protein LOC284274 & 18q23 & 18 & 71250814 & 71268577 & 0.013247 \\

    55 & C7orf20 & hypothetical protein LOC51608 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 882716 & 902597 & 0.047191 \\

    56 & C7orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC79034 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6596439 & 6614880 & 0.047191 \\

    57 & C7orf27 & hypothetical protein LOC221927 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2544038 & 2561672 & 0.047191 \\

    58 & C7orf28A & hypothetical protein LOC51622 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5904866 & 5932129 & 0.047191 \\

    59 & C7orf28B & hypothetical protein LOC221960 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6805096 & 6832386 & 0.047191 \\

    60 & C7orf50 & hypothetical protein LOC84310 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 1003167 & 1144402 & 0.047191 \\

    61 & C9orf167 & hypothetical protein LOC54863 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139292100 & 139296914 & 9.5724e-06 \\

    62 & CACNA1C & calcium channel, voltage-dependent, L type, & 12p13.33 & 12 & 2032724 & 2677376 & 7.1656e-06 \\

    63 & CARD11 & caspase recruitment domain family, member 11 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2912294 & 3050105 & 0.047191 \\

    64 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 4 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41718925 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

    65 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 1 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

    66 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 2 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

    67 & CBLN2 & cerebellin 2 precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 68354894 & 68362542 & 0.013247 \\

    68 & CBWD3 & COBW domain containing 3 & 9q12 & 9 & 70046658 & 70104752 & 6.1556e-08 \\

    69 & CBWD5 & COBW domain containing 5 & 9q12 & 9 & 69671823 & 69729991 & 6.1556e-08 \\

    70 & CBWD6 & COBW domain containing 6 & 9q12 & 9 & 68494357 & 68552413 & 6.1556e-08 \\

    71 & CCBE1 & collagen and calcium binding EGF domains 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 55252126 & 55515570 & 0.013247 \\

    72 & CCDC102B & coiled-coil domain containing 102B & 18q23 & 18 & 64533470 & 64873406 & 0.013247 \\

    73 & CCDC11 & coiled-coil domain containing 11 & 18q23 & 18 & 46007561 & 46046863 & 0.013247 \\

    74 & CCDC125 & coiled-coil domain containing 125 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68612274 & 68652166 & 9.8166e-07 \\

    75 & CCDC29 & coiled-coil domain containing 29 & 9q12 & 9 & 68715487 & 68738681 & 6.1556e-08 \\

    76 & CCDC5 & coiled-coil domain containing 5 (spindle & 18q23 & 18 & 41938322 & 41962297 & 0.013247 \\

    77 & CCDC68 & coiled-coil domain containing 68 & 18q23 & 18 & 50719790 & 50777635 & 0.013247 \\

    78 & CCNB1 & cyclin B1 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68498668 & 68509826 & 9.8166e-07 \\

    79 & CD226 & CD226 molecule precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 65681172 & 65775212 & 0.013247 \\

    80 & CDH19 & cadherin 19, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 62322300 & 62422196 & 0.013247 \\

    81 & CDH20 & cadherin 20, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 57308754 & 57373345 & 0.013247 \\

    82 & CDH7 & cadherin 7, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 61569136 & 61699154 & 0.013247 \\

    83 & CDK7 & cyclin-dependent kinase 7 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68566377 & 68609013 & 9.8166e-07 \\

    84 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

    85 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 3 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

    86 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 4 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21984490 & 2.3804e-08 \\

    87 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 2 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

    88 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

    89 & CDT1 & omatin licensing and DNA replication factor & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87397686 & 87403167 & 8.6264e-05 \\

    90 & CENPH & centromere protein H & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68521130 & 68541940 & 9.8166e-07 \\

    91 & CENTA1 & centaurin, alpha 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 904065 & 960793 & 0.047191 \\
  \end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering: how could I align the title inputs to each column?

Comment: That is, you want them left-aligned? By default they're centred, both vertically an horizontally.

Comment: Yes, I would like them left-aligned. :) Your code is impressive! I have started learning latex to write my thesis. It takes some time, but once I learn it, it will be very useful for other research projects.

Comment: I changed the code to have column heads  left-aligned (and in boldface, but you easily can change that). See my updated answer.

Comment: Please don't use two consecutive `\bottomrule` directives. A single instance should suffice.

Comment: @Mico: I know,  but it was in the O.P.'s original post. After all it's an aesthetic choice, not so  questionable as vertical rules (double rules could be used in professional typography in the 19th century).

Comment: The OP had two `\hline` directives, not two `\bottomrule` directives. Since `\bottomrule` is already quite a bit thicker than `\hline`, it's overkill to use two `\bottomrule`s.

Comment: It's easy to change their thickness (the default is $\approx$ 0.9pt). I preferred \bottomrules to \hlines because of the vertical padding that is added above it.

Comment: Simon Fear, the author of the `booktabs` package, gives the following advice in section 2 of the package's user guide: "You will not go far wrong if you remember two guidelines at all times: 1. Never, ever use vertical rules. 2. Never use double rules." :-)

Comment: I know, I often have to look at the doc to check some parameter/technical details. It remains that  every rule may suffer exceptions (except thiis one!). Although  I very rarely use them, I admit even vertical rules may make sense, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I halved `\tabcolsep`, changed some numeric columns from `l` to `r` and added some `booktabs` rules to have a but of extra space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.01in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\centering
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{3}{l} 
                     *{3}{r}
                     l}
  \caption{Deleted Genes in Claudin-low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue \\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \midrule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Gene} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Description} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cytoband} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Chr} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Start} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{End} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{qValue} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & 15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 3.3447e-37 \\

2 & A26C2 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 14q11.1 & 14 & 18623364 & 18654942 & 4.3278e-15 \\

3 & A26C3 & ANKRD26-like family C, member 3 & 22q11.1 & 22 & 14636331 & 14667937 & 1.4147e-06 \\

4 & ACAA2 & acetyl-coenzyme A acyltransferase 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 45563871 & 45594249 & 0.013247 \\

5 & ACOT1 & acyl-CoA thioesterase 1 & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73073680 & 73080251 & 0.0010389 \\

6 & ACOT2 & peroxisomal long-chain acyl-coA thioesterase & 14q24.3 & 14 & 73105524 & 73112112 & 0.0010389 \\

7 & ACTB & beta actin & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5533304 & 5536758 & 0.047191 \\

8 & ADNP2 & ADNP homeobox 2 & 18q23 & 18 & 75967902 & 75999219 & 0.013247 \\

9 & ALPK2 & heart alpha-kinase & 18q23 & 18 & 54299461 & 54447169 & 0.013247 \\

10 & AMZ1 & archaelysin family metallopeptidase 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2685688 & 2721595 & 0.047191 \\

11 & ANKRD20A1 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A1 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67559660 & 3.4893e-07 \\

12 & ANKRD20A2 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A2 & 9p11.2 & 9 & 43080420 & 43123540 & 6.0142e-10 \\

13 & ANKRD20A3 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A3 & 9p11.1 & 9 & 67516580 & 67560113 & 3.4893e-07 \\

14 & ANKRD20A4 & ankyrin repeat domain 20 family, member A4 & 9q12 & 9 & 68671800 & 68714929 & 6.1556e-08 \\

15 & ANKRD36B & ankyrin repeat domain 36B & 2q11.2 & 2 & 97487692 & 97572761 & 0.0040168 \\

16 & ANXA8 & annexin A8 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577989 & 46594128 & 1.9688e-14 \\

17 & ANXA8L1 & annexin A8-like 1 & 10q11.22 & 10 & 46577994 & 46594046 & 1.9688e-14 \\

18 & APC & adenomatous polyposis coli & 5q22.2 & 5 & 112101482 & 112209835 & 0.00017869 \\

19 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & 3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.7782e-08 \\

20 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform b & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

21 & APRT & adenine phosphoribosyltransferase isoform a & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87403377 & 87405843 & 8.6264e-05 \\

22 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform a & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6905712 & 0.054621 \\

23 & ARHGAP28 & Rho GTPase activating protein 28 isoform b & 18p11.31 & 18 & 6824483 & 6888720 & 0.054621 \\

24 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41772521 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

25 & ARL17 & ADP-ribosylation factor-like 17 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41732689 & 41794876 & 1.8812e-05 \\

26 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform b & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41949383 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

27 & ARL17P1 & hypothetical protein LOC51326 isoform a & 17q21.31 & 17 & 41985437 & 42012404 & 1.8812e-05 \\

28 & ATP5A1 & ATP synthase, H+ transporting, mitochondrial F1 & 18q23 & 18 & 41918107 & 41938197 & 0.013247 \\

29 & ATP8B1 & ATPase, class I, type 8B, member 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 53464656 & 53550037 & 0.013247 \\

30 & ATP9B & ATPase, class II, type 9B & 18q23 & 18 & 74930384 & 75239270 & 0.013247 \\

31 & BAGE & B melanoma antigen & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10079666 & 10120808 & 8.6688e-14 \\

32 & BAGE2 & B melanoma antigen family, member 2 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

33 & BAGE3 & B melanoma antigen family, member 3 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

34 & BAGE4 & B melanoma antigen family, member 4 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

35 & BAGE5 & B melanoma antigen family, member 5 & 21p11.1 & 21 & 10042712 & 10120796 & 8.6688e-14 \\

36 & BAHCC1 & BAH domain and coiled-coil containing 1 & 17q25.3 & 17 & 76988134 & 77047953 & 2.5467e-21 \\

37 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 beta isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 59136166 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

38 & BCL2 & B-cell lymphoma protein 2 alpha isoform & 18q23 & 18 & 58941558 & 59137593 & 0.013247 \\

39 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform g & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

40 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform a & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

41 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform d & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

42 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform c & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

43 & C16orf13 & hypothetical protein LOC84326 isoform b & 16p13.3 & 16 & 624429 & 626348 & 0.053767 \\

44 & C16orf14 & hypothetical protein LOC84331 & 16p13.3 & 16 & 631849 & 638475 & 0.053767 \\

45 & C18orf22 & hypothetical protein LOC79863 & 18q23 & 18 & 75895345 & 75907377 & 0.013247 \\

46 & C18orf24 & spindle and KT associated 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 46155389 & 46174536 & 0.013247 \\

47 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform b & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

48 & C18orf25 & ARKadia-like 1 isoform a & 18q23 & 18 & 42007985 & 42100953 & 0.013247 \\

49 & C18orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC284254 & 18q23 & 18 & 50409387 & 50417722 & 0.013247 \\

50 & C18orf32 & hypothetical protein LOC497661 & 18q23 & 18 & 45262027 & 45267599 & 0.013247 \\

51 & C18orf51 & hypothetical protein LOC125704 & 18q23 & 18 & 70253942 & 70276159 & 0.013247 \\

52 & C18orf54 & hypothetical protein LOC162681 & 18q23 & 18 & 50139168 & 50162381 & 0.013247 \\

53 & C18orf55 & hypothetical protein LOC29090 & 18q23 & 18 & 69966725 & 69977184 & 0.013247 \\

54 & C18orf62 & hypothetical protein LOC284274 & 18q23 & 18 & 71250814 & 71268577 & 0.013247 \\

55 & C7orf20 & hypothetical protein LOC51608 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 882716 & 902597 & 0.047191 \\

56 & C7orf26 & hypothetical protein LOC79034 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6596439 & 6614880 & 0.047191 \\

57 & C7orf27 & hypothetical protein LOC221927 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2544038 & 2561672 & 0.047191 \\

58 & C7orf28A & hypothetical protein LOC51622 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 5904866 & 5932129 & 0.047191 \\

59 & C7orf28B & hypothetical protein LOC221960 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 6805096 & 6832386 & 0.047191 \\

60 & C7orf50 & hypothetical protein LOC84310 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 1003167 & 1144402 & 0.047191 \\

61 & C9orf167 & hypothetical protein LOC54863 & 9q34.3 & 9 & 139292100 & 139296914 & 9.5724e-06 \\

62 & CACNA1C & calcium channel, voltage-dependent, L type, & 12p13.33 & 12 & 2032724 & 2677376 & 7.1656e-06 \\

63 & CARD11 & caspase recruitment domain family, member 11 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 2912294 & 3050105 & 0.047191 \\

64 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 4 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41718925 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

65 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 1 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

66 & CATSPER2 & sperm-associated cation channel 2 isoform 2 & 15q15.3 & 15 & 41710063 & 41728331 & 8.7732e-10 \\

67 & CBLN2 & cerebellin 2 precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 68354894 & 68362542 & 0.013247 \\

68 & CBWD3 & COBW domain containing 3 & 9q12 & 9 & 70046658 & 70104752 & 6.1556e-08 \\

69 & CBWD5 & COBW domain containing 5 & 9q12 & 9 & 69671823 & 69729991 & 6.1556e-08 \\

70 & CBWD6 & COBW domain containing 6 & 9q12 & 9 & 68494357 & 68552413 & 6.1556e-08 \\

71 & CCBE1 & collagen and calcium binding EGF domains 1 & 18q23 & 18 & 55252126 & 55515570 & 0.013247 \\

72 & CCDC102B & coiled-coil domain containing 102B & 18q23 & 18 & 64533470 & 64873406 & 0.013247 \\

73 & CCDC11 & coiled-coil domain containing 11 & 18q23 & 18 & 46007561 & 46046863 & 0.013247 \\

74 & CCDC125 & coiled-coil domain containing 125 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68612274 & 68652166 & 9.8166e-07 \\

75 & CCDC29 & coiled-coil domain containing 29 & 9q12 & 9 & 68715487 & 68738681 & 6.1556e-08 \\

76 & CCDC5 & coiled-coil domain containing 5 (spindle & 18q23 & 18 & 41938322 & 41962297 & 0.013247 \\

77 & CCDC68 & coiled-coil domain containing 68 & 18q23 & 18 & 50719790 & 50777635 & 0.013247 \\

78 & CCNB1 & cyclin B1 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68498668 & 68509826 & 9.8166e-07 \\

79 & CD226 & CD226 molecule precursor & 18q23 & 18 & 65681172 & 65775212 & 0.013247 \\

80 & CDH19 & cadherin 19, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 62322300 & 62422196 & 0.013247 \\

81 & CDH20 & cadherin 20, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 57308754 & 57373345 & 0.013247 \\

82 & CDH7 & cadherin 7, type 2 preproprotein & 18q23 & 18 & 61569136 & 61699154 & 0.013247 \\

83 & CDK7 & cyclin-dependent kinase 7 & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68566377 & 68609013 & 9.8166e-07 \\

84 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

85 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 3 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21965038 & 2.3804e-08 \\

86 & CDKN2A & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2A isoform 4 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21957750 & 21984490 & 2.3804e-08 \\

87 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 2 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

88 & CDKN2B & cyclin-dependent kinase inhibitor 2B isoform 1 & 9p21.3 & 9 & 21992901 & 21999312 & 2.3804e-08 \\

89 & CDT1 & omatin licensing and DNA replication factor & 16q24.3 & 16 & 87397686 & 87403167 & 8.6264e-05 \\

90 & CENPH & centromere protein H & 5q13.2 & 5 & 68521130 & 68541940 & 9.8166e-07 \\

91 & CENTA1 & centaurin, alpha 1 & 7p22.1 & 7 & 904065 & 960793 & 0.047191 \\
\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```