# Table of content and Table runs beyond page

Tags: tables, macros, formatting, line-spacing

Upon inserting a table, it runs beyond page [image: table and text run beyond page]
I tried inserting \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
but it messes up my spacing between chapter, sections and subsections gaps become automatically huge [image: gaps between titles]

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: "float too large by 746pt" sounds like a very large table. Be aware that tables can not break across pages.

Comment: For large tables, consider using either the `longtable` package, or if it is wide too, consider the options in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/table-and-multi-page

Comment: Seems you tried to convey two facts. What is the question? ;-)  Do you wish to know how to have different paper-sizes within the same document so you can create a larger sheet of paper for your table? Can you provide examples/instructions for reproducing the problem?